# Example of NSAttributedString with two different font sizes?

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

`NSAttributedString` is just really impenetrable to me.

I want to set a `UILabel` to have text of different sizes, and I gather `NSAttributedString` is the way to go, but I can't get anywhere with the documentation on this.

I would love it if someone could help me with a concrete example.

For instance, let's say the text I wanted was:

```
(in small letters:) "Presenting The Great..."
(in huge letters:) "HULK HOGAN!"
```

Can somebody show me how to do that? Or even, a reference that's plain and simple where I could learn for myself? I swear I've tried to understand this through the documentation, and even through other examples on Stack Overflow, and I'm just not getting it.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Suppose your input text is “Some of this text is larger than the rest,” and you want to change the size of the word “larger.” Here’s how you would do it:

```swift
let text = NSMutableAttributedString(
    "Some of this text is larger than the rest"
)

let range = text.mutableString.range(of: "larger")

if range.location != NSNotFound {
    text.addAttribute(.font,
                      value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20),
                      range: range)
}
```

Or in Objective-C,

```objectivec
NSMutableAttributedString *text = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
    initWithString:@"Some of this text is larger than the rest"];

NSRange range = [text rangeOfString:@"larger"];

if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
    [text addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                 value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0]
                 range:range];
}
```

The thing that might be confusing about setting the text size specifically is that you have to set the typeface *and* the size at the same time—each `UIFont` object encapsulates both of those properties.

See [the documentation of `NSAttributedString.Key`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/key) for the full list of `NSAttributedString` attributes.

Comment: Check out this answer for SWIFT ranges: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27041376/1736679

Comment: better to calculate the range of string instead of manually entering.
Use:

NSRange hulkRange = [@"Presenting the great... Hulk Hogan!" rangeOfString: @"Hulk Hogan!"];

Answer (score 24):

**Swift 3 Solution**

Also, you can use the `append` function instead of specifying indices in ObjC or Swift:

```
let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Presenting The Great...",
                                           attributes: [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20) ])

attrString.append(NSMutableAttributedString(string: "HULK HOGAN!",
                                            attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 40) ]))
```

Comment: Smarter than the accepted.

Answer (score 22):

**[UPDATE] Swift 5 Solution:**

```
let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Presenting The Great...",
                                           attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)]);

attrString.append(NSMutableAttributedString(string: "HULK HOGAN!",
                                            attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 36)]));
```

**Swift 4 Solution:**

```
let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Presenting The Great...",
                                       attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)]);

attrString.append(NSMutableAttributedString(string: "HULK HOGAN!",
                                        attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 36)]));
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do it the easy way, there is a git repo called [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel/) that I use that provides a category on NSAttributedString. It lets you do things like:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *mystring = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"My String"];
[mystring setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRGB:78 green:111 blue:32 alpha:1]];
mystring.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
```

If you don't want to use a 3rd party lib, check out [this link](http://soulwithmobiletechnology.blogspot.com/2012/07/how-to-use-nsattributedstring-in-ios-6.html) for a decent tutorial on how to get started with attributed strings.