# How can I change the text size without effecting the results text

Tags: xcode5

Can I format the "ltr's per pipe" text to a smaller size without effecting the actual result text?
Is it possible to do in the code here instead of adding extra labels?

Thanks.

```
pumpSpeedAnswer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ltr's per min.", numberAsString2];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can us the ["`attributedText`" property of your UILabel](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/attributedText) to change the font size of an arbitrary portion of your string.

[This related question has a nice example of how to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365631/example-of-nsattributedstring-with-two-different-font-sizes).

Comment: Thanks Michael, but I can't seem to get it working, how exactly do i use it with the above code? I will try again tomorrow as have a flight to catch.