# UILabel Bold / Highlight All occurrences SubString

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uilabel, textkit

I have multiple UILabels within a Custom Table cell. These labels contain varied text or varied length.

As it stands i have UILabel Subclassed allowing me to implement these methods

```
- (void)boldRange:(NSRange)range {
if (![self respondsToSelector:@selector(setAttributedText:)]) {
    return;
}
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText;
if (!self.attributedText) {
    attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.text];
} else {
    attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithAttributedString:self.attributedText];
}
     [attributedText setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:self.font.pointSize]} range:range];
self.attributedText = attributedText;
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromRange(range));
}

- (void)boldSubstring:(NSString*)substring {
    NSRange range = [self.text rangeOfString:substring];
    [self boldRange:range];
}
```

This allows me to call `[cell.StoryLabel boldSubstring:@"test"];` which will **BOLD** the first occurrence of the word 'test'.

What i am after is the ability to either create new subclass methods or extend the ones i already have, to allow me to replace ALL occurrences of a specified word within the label.

I have looked into a number of methods including 3rd party frameworks. The trouble i have  is this is a learning process for me. I would be far more beneficial for me to try and complete this myself.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `rangeOfString` returns the first occurrence, that's normal behavior. You could use a `NSRegularExpression`, and use `matchesInString:options:range` to get a `NSArray` of `NSRange`, an use a for loop to bold it.

Comment: How would i set the `[attributedText setAttributes:` for multiple though?

Comment: http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/format-text-in-ios6-attributed-strings

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365631/example-of-nsattributedstring-with-two-different-font-sizes

Comment: @Macrosoft-Dev : The issue is not about how bold (add "effects to `NSAttributedString`), but how to find subString...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rangeOfString` returns the first occurrence, that's normal behavior.
From the [Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString%3a):

> Finds and returns the range of the first occurrence of a given string
>   within the receiver.

You could use a `NSRegularExpression`, and use `matchesInString:options:range` to get a `NSArray` of `NSTextCheckingResult` (that have a `NSRange` property), an use a `for loop` to bold it.

This should do the trick:

```
- (void)boldSubstring:(NSString*)substring
{
    if (![self respondsToSelector:@selector(setAttributedText:)])
    {
        return;
    }

    NSError *error;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern: substring options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

    if (!error)
    {
        NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[self text]];
        NSArray *allMatches = [regex matchesInString:[self text] options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [[self text] length])];
        for (NSTextCheckingResult *aMatch in allMatches)
        {
            NSRange matchRange = [aMatch range];
            [attributedString setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:self.font.pointSize]} range: matchRange];
        }
        [self setAttributedText:attributedString];
    }
}
```

Comment: I implemented you method but it doesn't seems to be working. The text that i am trying to highlight is still the same as the rest

Comment: I got it working. I forgot earlier a line (setting the attributedText to self), did you add it?

Comment: Im not sure, which line are you talking about?

Comment: I added:`[self setAttributedText:attributedString];`. Check in debug if `error` is not null. Check also if `[allMatches count]` is different than 0 in debugger.