# iOS: set textview font to body programmatically

Tags: ios, xcode5, uitextview, uifont

I know how to set font programmatically when it comes to things like system fonts or custom fonts. But how do I specify the body font style? or caption or headline, for that matter?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way, you can modify it for your need.

```
attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody]}
```

For the others, replace body with say headline, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for setting attributed string using NSAttributedString.

You alloc and init the NSAttributed string object set the attributes like body fonts and  or headline etc.

Moreover, you can set the HTML text in the attributed text.

I hope the following links might help you...

[Example of NSAttributedString with two different font sizes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365631/example-of-nsattributedstring-with-two-different-font-sizes)

http://sketchytech.blogspot.in/2013/11/making-most-of-uitextview-in-ios-7.html

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, you have to create a font with the class function called `preferredFont` from `UIFont`:

```
let label1 = UILabel()
label1.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)

let label2 = UILabel()
label2.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .caption1)

let label3 = UILabel()
label3.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .headline)
```

You can find all the text styles here:

[UIFont.TextStyle documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont/textstyle)