# NSRange from Swift Range?

Tags: ios, macos, swift, nsrange

**Problem:** NSAttributedString takes an NSRange while I'm using a Swift String that uses Range

```
let text = "Long paragraph saying something goes here!"
let textRange = text.startIndex..<text.endIndex
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)

text.enumerateSubstringsInRange(textRange, options: NSStringEnumerationOptions.ByWords, { (substring, substringRange, enclosingRange, stop) -> () in

    if (substring == "saying") {
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: NSColor.redColor(), range: substringRange)
    }
})
```

**Produces the following error:**

> error: 'Range' is not convertible to 'NSRange'
>           attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: NSColor.redColor(), range: substringRange)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSRange to Range<String.Index>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25138339/nsrange-to-rangestring-index)

Comment: @Suhaib that's going the other way around.

Answer (score 304, accepted):

Swift `String` ranges and `NSString` ranges are not "compatible".
For example, an emoji like  counts as one Swift character, but as two `NSString`
characters (a so-called UTF-16 surrogate pair).

Therefore your suggested solution will produce unexpected results if the string
contains such characters. Example:

```
let text = "Long paragraph saying!"
let textRange = text.startIndex..<text.endIndex
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)

text.enumerateSubstringsInRange(textRange, options: NSStringEnumerationOptions.ByWords, { (substring, substringRange, enclosingRange, stop) -> () in
    let start = distance(text.startIndex, substringRange.startIndex)
    let length = distance(substringRange.startIndex, substringRange.endIndex)
    let range = NSMakeRange(start, length)

    if (substring == "saying") {
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: NSColor.redColor(), range: range)
    }
})
println(attributedString)
```

Output:

```
Long paragra{
}ph say{
    NSColor = "NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1";
}ing!{
}
```

As you see, "ph say" has been marked with the attribute, not "saying".

Since `NS(Mutable)AttributedString` ultimately requires an `NSString` and an `NSRange`, it is actually
better to convert the given string to `NSString` first. Then the `substringRange`
is an `NSRange` and you don't have to convert the ranges anymore:

```
let text = "Long paragraph saying!"
let nsText = text as NSString
let textRange = NSMakeRange(0, nsText.length)
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: nsText)

nsText.enumerateSubstringsInRange(textRange, options: NSStringEnumerationOptions.ByWords, { (substring, substringRange, enclosingRange, stop) -> () in

    if (substring == "saying") {
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: NSColor.redColor(), range: substringRange)
    }
})
println(attributedString)
```

Output:

```
Long paragraph {
}saying{
    NSColor = "NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1";
}!{
}
```

**Update for Swift 2:**

```
let text = "Long paragraph saying!"
let nsText = text as NSString
let textRange = NSMakeRange(0, nsText.length)
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)

nsText.enumerateSubstringsInRange(textRange, options: .ByWords, usingBlock: {
    (substring, substringRange, _, _) in

    if (substring == "saying") {
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: NSColor.redColor(), range: substringRange)
    }
})
print(attributedString)
```

**Update for Swift 3:**

```
let text = "Long paragraph saying!"
let nsText = text as NSString
let textRange = NSMakeRange(0, nsText.length)
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)

nsText.enumerateSubstrings(in: textRange, options: .byWords, using: {
    (substring, substringRange, _, _) in

    if (substring == "saying") {
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: NSColor.red, range: substringRange)
    }
})
print(attributedString)
```

**Update for Swift 4:**

As of Swift 4 (Xcode 9), the Swift standard library
provides method to convert between `Range<String.Index>` and `NSRange`.
Converting to `NSString` is no longer necessary:

```
let text = "Long paragraph saying!"
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)

text.enumerateSubstrings(in: text.startIndex..<text.endIndex, options: .byWords) {
    (substring, substringRange, _, _) in
    if substring == "saying" {
        attributedString.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: NSColor.red,
                                      range: NSRange(substringRange, in: text))
    }
}
print(attributedString)
```

Here `substringRange` is a `Range<String.Index>`, and that is converted to the
corresponding `NSRange` with

```
NSRange(substringRange, in: text)
```

Comment: For anyone wanting to type emoji characters on OSX - Control-Command-space bar brings up a character picker

Comment: This doesn't work if I'm matching more than one word, and I'm not sure what the entire string to match is. Say I'm getting a string back from an API and using it within another string, and I want the string from the API to be underlined, I cannot guarantee that the substrings won't be in both the string from the API and the other string! Any ideas?

Comment: NSMakeRange Changed str.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: str.startIndex, end: str.endIndex)) //"Hello, playground" this the changes

Comment: (or)   casting the string ---let substring = (string as NSString).substringWithRange(NSMakeRange(start, length))

Comment: @HariKrishnan.P: Sorry, I don't get what you are saying. There is no "substringWithRange" in the question or answer, and I have double-checked again that the suggested Swift 2 and Swift 3 code compiles and works as expected.

Comment: You mention that `Range<String.Index>` and `NSString` are not compatible. Are their counterparts also incompatible? I.e. are `NSRange` and `String` incompatible? Cause one of Apple's API specifically combines the two: [matches(in:options:range:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsregularexpression/1412446-matches)

Comment: @Senseful: Same problem there, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880650/swift-extract-regex-matches.

Comment: If you're dealing with content that's strictly 8-bit-chararacter encoded, your first example (using `NSMakeRange()`) will indeed work reliably.  I.E, If the string in question was created with `String(contentsOf: filepath, encoding: .ascii)` then the above warnings do not apply.

Comment: `Cannot convert value of type 'NSRange' (aka '_NSRange') to expected argument type 'Range<String.Index>' (aka 'Range<String.CharacterView.Index>')`

Comment: @IulianOnofrei: Strange. I have double-checked that the Swift 3 version still compiles in my Xcode 8.3.2. Which Xcode are you using?

Comment: @MartinR, Same latest version. Is that iOS only? As I'm trying to use that in a server.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei: On macOS or on Linux?

Comment: @MartinR, I tried it on macOS and it didn't work, but I'm planning to run it on Linux.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei: There was a small error in the Swift 3 code (`NSColor.red()` should be  `NSColor.red`), but apart from that it compiles without problems in a command-line macOS application. Did you import Foundation? For `NSColor` you also have to import AppKit. – There may be problems on Linux, this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/40093509/1187415 to a similar question might help.

Comment: @MartinR, I did import `Foundation` but didn't use the `NSColor` code part, just the range one. I will test again and let you know.

Comment: @MartinR, in your Swift 4 example, I think `substringRange` is actually a `Range<String.Index>` and is converted to `NSRange` with `NSRange(substringRange, in: text)`.

Comment: @jregnauld: I have rejected your edit suggestion because it completely broke the formatting. Why do you think that the Swift 3 version is wrong? Please let me know if there are problems with this answer.

Comment: What if you want to search by a string that contains more than one word. I am not getting this. @MartinR

Comment: @MartinR, seems like "NSRange(substringRange, in: text)" is broken for iOS 16!

Comment: @AnkitJayaswal: I have just tested the Swift 4 version of my answer in the iOS 16 simulator, and it works as expected. What do you think is broken?

Comment: @MartinR I am testing with xcode 14.0.1 with swift 5 and for iOS 16 device with following condition. 
let string = "Get the perfect solution\nfor your needs"
let subString = “for your needs"
let subTextRange = string.range(of: subString)
let range = NSRange(subTextRange, in: subString)

Error in last line: Swift/StringUTF16View.swift:249: Fatal error: String index is out of bounds. It is working till iOS 15.5 devices.

Comment: @AnkitJayaswal: `subTextRange` is a range in `string`, not in `subString`, therefore you must only call `let range = NSRange(subTextRange, in: string)`.  It may be that `NSRange(subTextRange, in: subString)` worked in earlier iOS versions by chance, but it was always undefined behaviour to use ranges/indices with anything but the original collection from which they are created.

Answer (score 64):

For cases like the one you described, I found this to work. It's relatively short and sweet:

```
 let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "follow the yellow brick road") //can essentially come from a textField.text as well (will need to unwrap though)
 let text = "follow the yellow brick road"
 let str = NSString(string: text) 
 let theRange = str.rangeOfString("yellow")
 attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.yellowColor(), range: theRange)
```

Comment: attributedString.addAttribute won't work with a swift Range

Comment: @Paludis, you are correct but this solution is not attempting to use a Swift range. It is using an `NSRange`. `str` is an `NSString` and therefore `str.RangeOfString()` returns an `NSRange`.

Comment: You can also remove the duplicate string in line 2 by replacing lines 2 and 3 with: `let str = attributedString.string as NSString`

Comment: This is a localization nightmare.

Answer (score 53):

The answers are fine, but with Swift 4 you could simplify your code a bit:

```
let text = "Test string"
let substring = "string"

let substringRange = text.range(of: substring)!
let nsRange = NSRange(substringRange, in: text)
```

Be cautious, as the result of `range` function has to be unwrapped.

Alternative solution:

```
let text = "Test string"
let substring = "string"

let range = text.range(of: substring).map { NSRange($0, in: text) } ?? NSRange()
```

Which would either return a valid range or an empty range. Otherwise, you'd need to handle the optionals.

Answer (score 13):

**Possible Solution**

Swift provides distance() which measures the distance between start and end that can be used to create an NSRange:

```
let text = "Long paragraph saying something goes here!"
let textRange = text.startIndex..<text.endIndex
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)

text.enumerateSubstringsInRange(textRange, options: NSStringEnumerationOptions.ByWords, { (substring, substringRange, enclosingRange, stop) -> () in
    let start = distance(text.startIndex, substringRange.startIndex)
    let length = distance(substringRange.startIndex, substringRange.endIndex)
    let range = NSMakeRange(start, length)

//    println("word: \(substring) - \(d1) to \(d2)")

        if (substring == "saying") {
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: NSColor.redColor(), range: range)
        }
})
```

Comment: Note: This can break if using characters like emoji in the string - See Martin's response.

Answer (score 9):

For me this works perfectly:

```
let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .medium)
let text = "text"
let attString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "exemple text :)")

attString.addAttributes([.font: font], range:(attString.string as NSString).range(of: text))

label.attributedText = attString
```

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 5 Solution**

Converting Range into NSRange

> As the **'encodedOffset'** is deprecated, so now in order to convert **String.Index** to **Int** we need the reference of original string from which **Range<String.Index>** was derived.

A convenient **detailed** extension for NSRange could be as below:

```swift
extension NSRange {

    public init(range: Range<String.Index>, 
                originalText: String) {

        let range_LowerBound_INDEX = range.lowerBound
        let range_UpperBound_INDEX = range.upperBound

        let range_LowerBound_INT = range_LowerBound_INDEX.utf16Offset(in: originalText)
        let range_UpperBound_INT = range_UpperBound_INDEX.utf16Offset(in: originalText)

        let locationTemp = range_LowerBound_INT
        let lengthTemp = range_UpperBound_INT - range_LowerBound_INT

        self.init(location: locationTemp,
                  length: lengthTemp)
    }
}
```

While the **shorthand** extension is as below

```swift
extension NSRange {

    public init(range: Range<String.Index>, 
                originalText: String) {

        self.init(location: range.lowerBound.utf16Offset(in: originalText),
                  length: range.upperBound.utf16Offset(in: originalText) - range.lowerBound.utf16Offset(in: originalText))
    }
}
```

Now we can use any Range to convert it into NSRange as below, sharing my own requirement which led me to write above extensions

I was using below String extension for finding all the ranges of specific word from the String

```swift
extension String {
        
    func ranges(of substring: String, options: CompareOptions = [], locale: Locale? = nil) -> [Range<Index>] {
        var ranges: [Range<Index>] = []
        while let range = range(of: substring, options: options, range: (ranges.last?.upperBound ?? self.startIndex)..<self.endIndex, locale: locale) {
            ranges.append(range)
        }
        return ranges
    }
}
```

My requirement was to change the colour of specific words in a String, so for that I wrote this extension which does the job

```swift
extension NSAttributedString {

    static func colored(originalText:String,
                        wordToColor:String,
                        currentColor:UIColor,
                        differentColor:UIColor) -> NSAttributedString {
        
        let attr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: originalText)
        
        attr.beginEditing()
        
        attr.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor,
                          value: currentColor,
                          range: NSRange(location: 0, length: originalText.count))
        
        // FOR COVERING ALL THE OCCURENCES
        for eachRange in originalText.ranges(of: wordToColor) {
            attr.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor,
                              value: differentColor,
                              range: NSRange(range: eachRange, originalText: originalText))
        }
        
        attr.endEditing()
        
        return attr
    }

}
```

Finally I was using it from my main code as below

```swift
let text = "Collected".localized() + "  +  " + "Cancelled".localized() + "  +  " + "Pending".localized()
myLabel.attributedText = NSAttributedString.colored(originalText: text,
                                                    wordToColor: "+",
                                                    currentColor: UIColor.purple,
                                                    differentColor: UIColor.blue)
```

And the result is as below, having the colour of + sign changed as blue from the main text colour which is purple.

[image]

Hope this helps someone in need. Thanks!

Comment: This extension was exactly what I needed; it's basically equivalent to Kotlin String extension `offsetByCodePoints`

Comment: @BryanW.Wagner glad to know that you find it useful.

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 4:**

Sure, I know that Swift 4 has an extension for NSRange already

```
public init<R, S>(_ region: R, in target: S) where R : RangeExpression,
    S : StringProtocol, 
    R.Bound == String.Index, S.Index == String.Index
```

I know in most cases this init is enough. See its usage:

```
let string = "Many animals here:  !!!"

if let range = string.range(of: ""){
     print((string as NSString).substring(with: NSRange(range, in: string))) //  ""
 }
```

But conversion can be done directly from Range< String.Index > to NSRange without Swift's String instance.

Instead of generic *init* usage which requires from you the *target* parameter as *String* and
if you don't have *target* string at hand you can create conversion directly

```
extension NSRange {
    public init(_ range:Range<String.Index>) {
        self.init(location: range.lowerBound.encodedOffset,
              length: range.upperBound.encodedOffset -
                      range.lowerBound.encodedOffset) }
    }
```

or you can create the specialized extension for Range itself

```
extension Range where Bound == String.Index {
    var nsRange:NSRange {
    return NSRange(location: self.lowerBound.encodedOffset,
                     length: self.upperBound.encodedOffset -
                             self.lowerBound.encodedOffset)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let string = "Many animals here:  !!!"
if let range = string.range(of: ""){
    print((string as NSString).substring(with: NSRange(range))) //  ""
}
```

or

```
if let nsrange = string.range(of: "")?.nsRange{
    print((string as NSString).substring(with: nsrange)) //  ""
}
```

**Swift 5:**

Due to the migration of Swift strings to UTF-8 encoding by default, the usage of `encodedOffset` is considered as deprecated and Range cannot be converted to NSRange without an instance of String itself, because in order to calculate the offset we need the source string which is encoded in UTF-8 and it should be converted to UTF-16 before calculating offset. So best approach, for now, is to use generic *init*.

Comment: The use of `encodedOffset` is [considered harmful](https://swift.org/blog/utf8-string/#use-of-stringindexencodedoffset-considered-harmful) and will be [deprecated](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0241-string-index-explicit-encoding-offset.md).

Comment: I have fixed encodedOffset issue, check [https://stackoverflow.com/a/68468499/2740218]

Comment: But you have to use original text that looks like existing extention as I wrote in the begining. My idea was in conversion without original text.
see: public init<R, S>(_ region: R, in target: S) where R : RangeExpression,
    S : StringProtocol, 
    R.Bound == String.Index, S.Index == String.Index

Answer (score 5):

Swift 4

I think, there are two ways.

**1. NSRange(range, in: )**

**2. NSRange(location:, length: )**

Sample code:

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Sample Text 12345", attributes: [.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15.0)])

// NSRange(range, in: )
if let range = attributedString.string.range(of: "Sample")  {
    attributedString.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.orange, range: NSRange(range, in: attributedString.string))
}

// NSRange(location: , length: )
if let range = attributedString.string.range(of: "12345") {
    attributedString.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.green, range: NSRange(location: range.lowerBound.encodedOffset, length: range.upperBound.encodedOffset - range.lowerBound.encodedOffset))
}
```

Screen Shot:
[image]

Comment: The use of `encodedOffset` is [considered harmful](https://swift.org/blog/utf8-string/#use-of-stringindexencodedoffset-considered-harmful) and will be [deprecated](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0241-string-index-explicit-encoding-offset.md).

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3 Extension Variant**  that preserves existing attributes.

```
extension UILabel {
  func setLineHeight(lineHeight: CGFloat) {
    guard self.text != nil && self.attributedText != nil else { return }
    var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()

    if let attributedText = self.attributedText {
      attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attributedText)
    } else if let text = self.text {
      attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
    }

    let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    style.lineSpacing = lineHeight
    style.alignment = self.textAlignment
    let str = NSString(string: attributedString.string)

    attributedString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName,
                                  value: style,
                                  range: str.range(of: str as String))
    self.attributedText = attributedString
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func formatAttributedStringWithHighlights(text: String, highlightedSubString: String?, formattingAttributes: [String: AnyObject]) -> NSAttributedString {
    let mutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)

    let text = text as NSString         // convert to NSString be we need NSRange
    if let highlightedSubString = highlightedSubString {
        let highlightedSubStringRange = text.rangeOfString(highlightedSubString) // find first occurence
        if highlightedSubStringRange.length > 0 {       // check for not found
            mutableString.setAttributes(formattingAttributes, range: highlightedSubStringRange)
        }
    }

    return mutableString
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I love the Swift language, but using `NSAttributedString` with a Swift `Range` that is not compatible with `NSRange` has made my head hurt for too long. So to get around all that garbage I devised the following methods to return an `NSMutableAttributedString` with the highlighted words set with your color.

This does **not** work for emojis. Modify if you must.

```
extension String {
    func getRanges(of string: String) -> [NSRange] {
        var ranges:[NSRange] = []
        if contains(string) {
            let words = self.components(separatedBy: " ")
            var position:Int = 0
            for word in words {
                if word.lowercased() == string.lowercased() {
                    let startIndex = position
                    let endIndex = word.characters.count
                    let range = NSMakeRange(startIndex, endIndex)
                    ranges.append(range)
                }
                position += (word.characters.count + 1) // +1 for space
            }
        }
        return ranges
    }
    func highlight(_ words: [String], this color: UIColor) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self)
        for word in words {
            let ranges = getRanges(of: word)
            for range in ranges {
                attributedString.addAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color], range: range)
            }
        }
        return attributedString
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// The strings you're interested in
let string = "The dog ran after the cat"
let words = ["the", "ran"]

// Highlight words and get back attributed string
let attributedString = string.highlight(words, this: .yellow)

// Set attributed string
label.attributedText = attributedString
```

Comment: "The ran" "ran after". Array of words in this case failing

Answer (score 0):

My solution is a string extension that first gets the swift range then get's the distance from the start of the string to the start and end of the substring.

These values are then used to calculate the start and length of the substring. We can then apply these values to the NSMakeRange constructor.

This solution works with substrings that consist of multiple words, which a lot of the solutions here using enumerateSubstrings let me down on.

```
extension String {

    func NSRange(of substring: String) -> NSRange? {
        // Get the swift range 
        guard let range = range(of: substring) else { return nil }

        // Get the distance to the start of the substring
        let start = distance(from: startIndex, to: range.lowerBound) as Int
        //Get the distance to the end of the substring
        let end = distance(from: startIndex, to: range.upperBound) as Int

        //length = endOfSubstring - startOfSubstring
        //start = startOfSubstring
        return NSMakeRange(start, end - start)
    }

}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
let text:String = "Hello Friend"

let searchRange:NSRange = NSRange(location:0,length: text.characters.count)

let range:Range`<Int`> = Range`<Int`>.init(start: searchRange.location, end: searchRange.length)
```

Comment: How about explaining your answer a bit, and preferably formatting the code properly?