# Swift extract regex matches

Tags: ios, regex, string, swift

I want to extract substrings from a string that match a regex pattern.

So I'm looking for something like this:

```
func matchesForRegexInText(regex: String!, text: String!) -> [String] {
   ???
}
```

So this is what I have:

```
func matchesForRegexInText(regex: String!, text: String!) -> [String] {

    var regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex, 
        options: nil, error: nil)

    var results = regex.matchesInString(text, 
        options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, countElements(text))) 
            as Array<NSTextCheckingResult>

    /// ???

    return ...
}
```

The problem is, that `matchesInString` delivers me an array of `NSTextCheckingResult`, where `NSTextCheckingResult.range` is of type `NSRange`.

`NSRange` is incompatible with `Range<String.Index>`, so it prevents me of using `text.substringWithRange(...)`

Any idea how to achieve this simple thing in swift without too many lines of code?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson "Fattie wants to reward an existing answer"

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yeah, but it is described on the [reasons page](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/09/23/bounty-reasons-and-post-notices/)

Comment: Feel free to delete resolved comments

Comment: Feel free to delete resolved comments @JoakimDanielson TY

Answer (score 384, accepted):

Even if the `matchesInString()` method takes a `String` as the first argument,
it works internally with `NSString`, and the range parameter must be given 
using the `NSString` length and not as the Swift string length. Otherwise it will
fail for "extended grapheme clusters" such as "flags".

As of **Swift 4** (Xcode 9), the Swift standard
library provides functions to convert between `Range<String.Index>` 
and `NSRange`.

```
func matches(for regex: String, in text: String) -> [String] {

    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex)
        let results = regex.matches(in: text,
                                    range: NSRange(text.startIndex..., in: text))
        return results.map {
            String(text[Range($0.range, in: text)!])
        }
    } catch let error {
        print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return []
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let string = "€4€9"
let matched = matches(for: "[0-9]", in: string)
print(matched)
// ["4", "9"]
```

*Note:* The forced unwrap `Range($0.range, in: text)!` is safe because
the `NSRange` refers to a substring of the given string `text`.
However, if you want to avoid it then use

```
        return results.flatMap {
            Range($0.range, in: text).map { String(text[$0]) }
        }
```

instead.

---

*(Older answer for Swift 3 and earlier:)*

So you should convert the given Swift string to an `NSString` and then extract the
ranges. The result will be converted to a Swift string array automatically.

(The code for Swift 1.2 can be found in the edit history.)

**Swift 2 (Xcode 7.3.1) :**

```
func matchesForRegexInText(regex: String, text: String) -> [String] {

    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex, options: [])
        let nsString = text as NSString
        let results = regex.matchesInString(text,
                                            options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, nsString.length))
        return results.map { nsString.substringWithRange($0.range)}
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return []
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let string = "€4€9"
let matches = matchesForRegexInText("[0-9]", text: string)
print(matches)
// ["4", "9"]
```

---

**Swift 3 (Xcode 8)**

```
func matches(for regex: String, in text: String) -> [String] {

    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex)
        let nsString = text as NSString
        let results = regex.matches(in: text, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: nsString.length))
        return results.map { nsString.substring(with: $0.range)}
    } catch let error {
        print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return []
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let string = "€4€9"
let matched = matches(for: "[0-9]", in: string)
print(matched)
// ["4", "9"]
```

Comment: You saved me from becoming insane. Not kidding. Thank you so much!

Comment: @MathijsSegers: I have updated the code for Swift 1.2/Xcode 6.3. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: but what if i want to search for strings between a tag? I need the same result (match information) like: https://regex101.com/r/cU6jX8/2. which regex pattern would you suggest?

Comment: The update is for Swift 1.2, not Swift 2. The code doesn't compile with Swift 2.

Comment: @pnollet: Strange. I have just double-checked that the "Swift 2" version compiles and runs with Xcode 7 GM, and it worked as expected. What error message do you get?

Comment: Thanks! What if you only want to extract what's actually between () in the regex? For example, in "[0-9]{3}([0-9]{6})" I'd only want to get the last 6 numbers.

Comment: If I try using this method to extract text between parentheses I get compile errors (using Swift 2) - the reg ex I am passing in is `"\((.*?)\)"`can anyone help?

Comment: @KevinMann Double backslash the special characters. You need to escape the string and the special character

Comment: The Swift 3 example here does not compile.  The try statement gives a compile error "Errors thrown from here are not handled"

Comment: @FuadKamal: That is strange. I have double-checked it with Xcode 8, and it compiles and runs as expected.

Comment: @MartinR it works for me now as well.  Didn't even have to do a clean...Xcode strangeness I guess ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Thanks for checking!

Comment: @MartinR shouldn't you check for nil?

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov: `$0.range` is an NSRange returned from `regex.matches(...)` as the range in the string which matches the given pattern. Therefore I think it is safe to assume that it can be converted back to a `Range<String.Index>`.

Comment: In Swift 4, the line `text.substring(with: Range($0.range, in: text)!)` generates a deprecated warning. I looked here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1418469-substring# and I don't see anything about deprecation. This answer has a solution to a slightly different problem, but I can't apply it to silence the warning. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45562662/how-can-i-use-string-slicing-subscripts-in-swift-4

Comment: @Adrian: You are right. The new version should work without warnings. Thanks for the notice!

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a solution without to force-unwrap the range!

Comment: @ixany: Have a look!

Comment: So much hassle just to extract a substring with a regex. It should be possible to do this with a single line of code. Unbelievable! Thanks!

Comment: I _like_ the `NSRange(text.startIndex..., in: text)` open range. +1

Comment: Not working if I am trying to find multiple quoted words in a  string: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57852915/find-multiple-quoted-words-in-a-string-with-regex

Comment: You can also remove the explicit unwrap by doing `return results.map { (text as NSString).substring(with: $0.range) }` I submitted an edit to the answer.

Comment: Still saving a lot of lives! :D

Answer (score 75):

My answer builds on top of given answers but makes regex matching more robust by adding additional support:

- Returns not only matches but **returns also all capturing groups** for each match (see examples below)
- Instead of returning an empty array, this solution **supports optional matches**
- Avoids `do/catch` by not printing to the console and **makes use of the `guard` construct**
- Adds `matchingStrings` as an **extension to `String`**

**Swift 4.2**

```swift
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Foundation

extension String {
    func matchingStrings(regex: String) -> [[String]] {
        guard let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex, options: []) else { return [] }
        let nsString = self as NSString
        let results  = regex.matches(in: self, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, nsString.length))
        return results.map { result in
            (0..<result.numberOfRanges).map {
                result.range(at: $0).location != NSNotFound
                    ? nsString.substring(with: result.range(at: $0))
                    : ""
            }
        }
    }
}

"prefix12 aaa3 prefix45".matchingStrings(regex: "fix([0-9])([0-9])")
// Prints: [["fix12", "1", "2"], ["fix45", "4", "5"]]

"prefix12".matchingStrings(regex: "(?:prefix)?([0-9]+)")
// Prints: [["prefix12", "12"]]

"12".matchingStrings(regex: "(?:prefix)?([0-9]+)")
// Prints: [["12", "12"]], other answers return an empty array here

// Safely accessing the capture of the first match (if any):
let number = "prefix12suffix".matchingStrings(regex: "fix([0-9]+)su").first?[1]
// Prints: Optional("12")
```

**Swift 3**

```swift
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Foundation

extension String {
    func matchingStrings(regex: String) -> [[String]] {
        guard let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex, options: []) else { return [] }
        let nsString = self as NSString
        let results  = regex.matches(in: self, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, nsString.length))
        return results.map { result in
            (0..<result.numberOfRanges).map {
                result.rangeAt($0).location != NSNotFound
                    ? nsString.substring(with: result.rangeAt($0))
                    : ""
            }
        }
    }
}

"prefix12 aaa3 prefix45".matchingStrings(regex: "fix([0-9])([0-9])")
// Prints: [["fix12", "1", "2"], ["fix45", "4", "5"]]

"prefix12".matchingStrings(regex: "(?:prefix)?([0-9]+)")
// Prints: [["prefix12", "12"]]

"12".matchingStrings(regex: "(?:prefix)?([0-9]+)")
// Prints: [["12", "12"]], other answers return an empty array here

// Safely accessing the capture of the first match (if any):
let number = "prefix12suffix".matchingStrings(regex: "fix([0-9]+)su").first?[1]
// Prints: Optional("12")
```

**Swift 2**

```
extension String {
    func matchingStrings(regex: String) -> [[String]] {
        guard let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex, options: []) else { return [] }
        let nsString = self as NSString
        let results  = regex.matchesInString(self, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, nsString.length))
        return results.map { result in
            (0..<result.numberOfRanges).map {
                result.rangeAtIndex($0).location != NSNotFound
                    ? nsString.substringWithRange(result.rangeAtIndex($0))
                    : ""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea about the capture groups. But why is "guard" Swiftier than "do/catch"??

Comment: I agree with people such as http://nshipster.com/guard-and-defer/ who say _Swift 2.0 certainly seems to be encouraging a style of early return [...] rather than nested if statements_. The same holds true for nested do/catch statements IMHO.

Comment: try/catch is the native error handling in Swift. `try?` can be used if you are only interested in the outcome of the call, not in a possible error message. So yes, `guard try? ..` is fine, but if you want to print the error then you need a do-block. Both ways are Swifty.

Comment: I agree that you need do/catch in your example if you want to see the error in the console. Since I want to provide a function that can be reused in production code without modifying it (`print` is an unwanted side effect for me), `guard try?` becomes a little Swiftier (if you don't need the side effect) – modified the answer to clarify. Thanks!

Comment: I have added unittests to your nice snippet, https://gist.github.com/neoneye/03cbb26778539ba5eb609d16200e4522

Comment: Was about to write my own based on the @MartinR answer until i saw this. Thanks!

Comment: Don't you think it is time to add Swift 4 version?

Comment: If I use this on a regex which can find quoted words in a sentence/string like this: `"hi \"how\", \"are\", you"`. The result is this: `[["\"how\", \"are\"", "how\", \"are"]]`. here is the regex which I am using: `"\"(.*)\""`

Answer (score 38):

## The fastest way to return all matches and capture groups in Swift 5

```swift
extension String {
    func match(_ regex: String) -> [[String]] {
        let nsString = self as NSString
        return (try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex, options: []))?.matches(in: self, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, nsString.length)).map { match in
            (0..<match.numberOfRanges).map { match.range(at: $0).location == NSNotFound ? "" : nsString.substring(with: match.range(at: $0)) }
        } ?? []
    }
}
```

**Returns a 2-dimentional array of strings:**

```swift
"prefix12suffix fix1su".match("fix([0-9]+)su")
```

**returns...**

```swift
[["fix12su", "12"], ["fix1su", "1"]]

// First element of sub-array is the match
// All subsequent elements are the capture groups
```

Comment: is `options: []` really required?

Comment: How do we know this is the fastest way to do it?

Comment: **Fantastic canned solution if not yet on iOS16**

Answer (score 15):

If you want to extract substrings from a String, not just the position, (but the actual String including emojis).  Then, the following maybe a simpler solution.

```
extension String {
  func regex (pattern: String) -> [String] {
    do {
      let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: NSRegularExpressionOptions(rawValue: 0))
      let nsstr = self as NSString
      let all = NSRange(location: 0, length: nsstr.length)
      var matches : [String] = [String]()
      regex.enumerateMatchesInString(self, options: NSMatchingOptions(rawValue: 0), range: all) {
        (result : NSTextCheckingResult?, _, _) in
        if let r = result {
          let result = nsstr.substringWithRange(r.range) as String
          matches.append(result)
        }
      }
      return matches
    } catch {
      return [String]()
    }
  }
}
```

Example Usage:

```
"someText ⚽️ pig".regex("⚽️")
```

Will return the following:

```
["⚽️"]
```

Note using "\w+" may produce an unexpected ""

```
"someText ⚽️ pig".regex("\\w+")
```

Will return this String array

```
["someText", "️", "pig"]
```

Comment: This is what I wanted

Comment: Nice! It needs a little adjustment for Swift 3, but it's great.

Comment: @Jelle what is the adjustment it needs? I'm using swift 5.1.3

Answer (score 13):

## Update for iOS 16: `Regex`, `RegexBuilder` ‍♀️

Xcode previously supported Regex with Apple's `NSRegularExpression`. The Swift API was verbose and challenging to use correctly, so Apple released `Regex Literal` support and `RegexBuilder` this year. The Regex flavor used by `Regex` types is the same as `NSRegularExpression`, i.e. the ICU Unicode specification.

The API has been simplified going forward to tidy up complex `String` range-based parsing logic in iOS 16 / macOS 13 as well as improve performance.

Another advantage of using literals is that we get compile time errors in case we use invalid RegEx syntax: `Cannot parse regular expression...` with a clear description of the RegEx error. Enjoy!

### RegEx literals in Swift 5.7

```
func parseLine(_ line: Substring) throws -> MailmapEntry {

    let regex = /\h*([^<#]+?)??\h*<([^>#]+)>\h*(?:#|\Z)/

    guard let match = line.prefixMatch(of: regex) else {
        throw MailmapError.badLine
    }

    return MailmapEntry(name: match.1, email: match.2)
}
```

We are able to match using:

1. [`firstMatch(of:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/bidirectionalcollection/firstmatch(of:)-6v8ci): Returns the first match for the regex within this collection, where the regex is created by the given closure (RegEx literal).
2. [`prefixMatch(of:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/bidirectionalcollection/prefixmatch(of:)-2fwv6): Returns a match if this string is matched by the given regex at its start.
3. [`wholeMatch(of:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/bidirectionalcollection/wholematch(of:)-1wbp6): Matches a regex in its entirety, where the regex is created by the given closure (RegEx literal).
4. [`matches(of:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/bidirectionalcollection/matches(of:)-5eey9): Returns a collection containing all non-overlapping matches of the regex, created by the given closure (RegEx literal).

I've linked to the docs above. The new RegEx literal syntax has multiple new APIs such as `trimmingPrefix()`, `contains()` and more, so I do encourage exploring the docs further for more nuanced use cases.

There is equivalent syntax of the above methods where we call `prefixMatch(in:)` on the Regex literal itself and pass in the string to search in. I prefer the syntax above however choose whichever you prefer.

Example code:

```
let aOrB = /[ab]+/

if let stringMatch = try aOrB.firstMatch(in: "The year is 2022; last year was 2021.") {
    print(stringMatch.0)
} else {
    print("No match.")
}
// prints "a"
```

### RegexBuilder in Swift 5.7

RegexBuilder is a new API released by Apple aimed at making RegEx code easier to write in Swift. We can translate the Regex literal `/\h*([^<#]+?)??\h*<([^>#]+)>\h*(?:#|\Z)/` from above into a more declarative form using RegexBuilder if we want more readability.

Do note that we can use raw strings in a RegexBuilder and also interleave Regex Literals in the builder if we want to balance readability with conciseness.

```
import RegexBuilder

let regex = Regex {
    ZeroOrMore(.horizontalWhitespace)
    Optionally {
        Capture(OneOrMore(.noneOf("<#")))
    }
        .repetitionBehavior(.reluctant)
    ZeroOrMore(.horizontalWhitespace)
    "<"
    Capture(OneOrMore(.noneOf(">#")))
    ">"
    ZeroOrMore(.horizontalWhitespace)
    /#|\Z/
}
```

The RegEx literal `/#|\Z/` is equivalent to:

```
ChoiceOf {
   "#"
   Anchor.endOfSubjectBeforeNewline
}
```

### Composable `RegexComponent`

`RegexBuilder` syntax is similar to SwiftUI also in terms of composability because we can reuse `RegexComponent`s within other `RegexComponent`s:

```
struct MailmapLine: RegexComponent {
    @RegexComponentBuilder
    var regex: Regex<(Substring, Substring?, Substring)> {
        ZeroOrMore(.horizontalWhitespace)
        Optionally {
            Capture(OneOrMore(.noneOf("<#")))
        }
            .repetitionBehavior(.reluctant)
        ZeroOrMore(.horizontalWhitespace)
        "<"
        Capture(OneOrMore(.noneOf(">#")))
        ">"
        ZeroOrMore(.horizontalWhitespace)
        ChoiceOf {
           "#"
            Anchor.endOfSubjectBeforeNewline
        }
    }
}
```

Source: Some of this code is taken from the WWDC 2022 video "What's new in Swift".

Answer (score 12):

I found that the accepted answer's solution unfortunately does not compile on Swift 3 for Linux. Here's a modified version, then, that does:

```
import Foundation

func matches(for regex: String, in text: String) -> [String] {
    do {
        let regex = try RegularExpression(pattern: regex, options: [])
        let nsString = NSString(string: text)
        let results = regex.matches(in: text, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: nsString.length))
        return results.map { nsString.substring(with: $0.range) }
    } catch let error {
        print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return []
    }
}
```

The main differences are:

1. Swift on Linux seems to require dropping the `NS` prefix on Foundation objects for which there is no Swift-native equivalent. (See [Swift evolution proposal #86](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0086-drop-foundation-ns.md).)
2. Swift on Linux also requires specifying the `options` arguments for both the `RegularExpression` initialization and the `matches` method.
3. For some reason, coercing a `String` into an `NSString` doesn't work in Swift on Linux but initializing a new `NSString` with a `String` as the source does work.

This version also works with Swift 3 on macOS / Xcode with the sole exception that you must use the name `NSRegularExpression` instead of `RegularExpression`.

Answer (score 7):

Swift 4 without NSString.

```
extension String {
    func matches(regex: String) -> [String] {
        guard let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex, options: [.caseInsensitive]) else { return [] }
        let matches  = regex.matches(in: self, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, self.count))
        return matches.map { match in
            return String(self[Range(match.range, in: self)!])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Be careful with above solution: `NSMakeRange(0, self.count)` is not correct, because `self` is a `String` (=UTF8) and not an `NSString` (=UTF16). So the `self.count` is not necessarily the same as `nsString.length` (as used in other solutions). You can replace the range calculation with `NSRange(self.startIndex..., in: self)`

Answer (score 5):

@p4bloch if you want to capture results from a series of capture parentheses, then you need to use the `rangeAtIndex(index)` method of `NSTextCheckingResult`, instead of `range`. Here's @MartinR 's method for Swift2 from above, adapted for capture parentheses. In the array that is returned, the first result `[0]` is the entire capture, and then individual capture groups begin from `[1]`. I commented out the `map` operation (so it's easier to see what I changed) and replaced it with nested loops.

```
func matches(for regex: String!, in text: String!) -> [String] {

    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex, options: [])
        let nsString = text as NSString
        let results = regex.matchesInString(text, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, nsString.length))
        var match = [String]()
        for result in results {
            for i in 0..<result.numberOfRanges {
                match.append(nsString.substringWithRange( result.rangeAtIndex(i) ))
            }
        }
        return match
        //return results.map { nsString.substringWithRange( $0.range )} //rangeAtIndex(0)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return []
    }
}
```

An example use case might be, say you want to split a string of `title year` eg "Finding Dory 2016" you could do this:

```
print ( matches(for: "^(.+)\\s(\\d{4})" , in: "Finding Dory 2016"))
// ["Finding Dory 2016", "Finding Dory", "2016"]
```

Comment: This answer made my day. I spent 2 hours searching for a solution that can satisfy regualr expression with the additional capturing of groups.

Comment: This works but it will crash if any range is not found. I modified this code so that the function returns `[String?]` and in the `for i in 0..<result.numberOfRanges` block, you have to add a test that only appends the match if the range != `NSNotFound`, otherwise it should append nil. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31892241/2805570

Answer (score 4):

Most of the solutions above only give the full match as a result ignoring the capture groups e.g.: ^\d+\s+(\d+)

To get the capture group matches as expected you need something like (Swift4) :

```
public extension String {
    public func capturedGroups(withRegex pattern: String) -> [String] {
        var results = [String]()

        var regex: NSRegularExpression
        do {
            regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])
        } catch {
            return results
        }
        let matches = regex.matches(in: self, options: [], range: NSRange(location:0, length: self.count))

        guard let match = matches.first else { return results }

        let lastRangeIndex = match.numberOfRanges - 1
        guard lastRangeIndex >= 1 else { return results }

        for i in 1...lastRangeIndex {
            let capturedGroupIndex = match.range(at: i)
            let matchedString = (self as NSString).substring(with: capturedGroupIndex)
            results.append(matchedString)
        }

        return results
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great if you're wanting just the first result, to get each result it needs `for index in 0..<matches.count {` around `let lastRange... results.append(matchedString)}`

Comment: the for clause should look like this: `for i in 1...lastRangeIndex {
            let capturedGroupIndex = match.range(at: i)
            
            if capturedGroupIndex.location != NSNotFound {
                let matchedString = (self as NSString).substring(with: capturedGroupIndex)
                results.append(matchedString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces))
            }
            
        }`

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it, I hope it brings a new perspective how this works on Swift.

In this example below I will get the any string between `[]`

```
var sample = "this is an [hello] amazing [world]"

var regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\[.+?\\]"
, options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive 
, error: nil)

var matches = regex?.matchesInString(sample, options: nil
, range: NSMakeRange(0, countElements(sample))) as Array<NSTextCheckingResult>

for match in matches {
   let r = (sample as NSString).substringWithRange(match.range)//cast to NSString is required to match range format.
    println("found= \(r)")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a very simple solution that returns an array of string with the matches

Swift 3.

```
internal func stringsMatching(regularExpressionPattern: String, options: NSRegularExpression.Options = []) -> [String] {
        guard let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: regularExpressionPattern, options: options) else {
            return []
        }

        let nsString = self as NSString
        let results = regex.matches(in: self, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, nsString.length))

        return results.map {
            nsString.substring(with: $0.range)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Be careful using NSMakeRange(0, self.count), because self is a String (=UTF8) and not an NSString (=UTF16). So the self.count is not necessarily the same as nsString.length (as used in other solutions). You can replace the range calculation with NSRange(self.startIndex..., in: self).

Answer (score 2):

update @Mike Chirico's to *Swift 5*

```
extension String{



  func regex(pattern: String) -> [String]?{
    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: NSRegularExpression.Options(rawValue: 0))
        let all = NSRange(location: 0, length: count)
        var matches = [String]()
        regex.enumerateMatches(in: self, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions(rawValue: 0), range: all) {
            (result : NSTextCheckingResult?, _, _) in
              if let r = result {
                    let nsstr = self as NSString
                    let result = nsstr.substring(with: r.range) as String
                    matches.append(result)
              }
        }
        return matches
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On iOS 16 there is new syntax that makes this way easier.
For example, for anything within brackets in this string

```
let randomLog = "2493875469750,1678798470864,{latitude: 50, longitude: 43}"

if let match = randomLog.firstMatch(of: /\{.*\}/) {
    print(match.output)
}
```

This prints

```
"{"latitude": 50, "longitude": 43}"
```

In order to become a Swift Regex Pro, or just for more info, have a look at WWDC 2022:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110357/

Comment: The new regex literal Swift syntax is part of Swift 5.7, not iOS 16. And other answers already cover this feature.

Answer (score 1):

Big thanks to [Lars Blumberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/543875/lars-blumberg) his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40040472/8970591) for capturing groups and full matches with **Swift 4**, which helped me out a lot. I also made an addition to it for the people who do want an error.localizedDescription response when their regex is invalid:

```
extension String {
    func matchingStrings(regex: String) -> [[String]] {
        do {
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex)
            let nsString = self as NSString
            let results  = regex.matches(in: self, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, nsString.length))
            return results.map { result in
                (0..<result.numberOfRanges).map {
                    result.range(at: $0).location != NSNotFound
                        ? nsString.substring(with: result.range(at: $0))
                        : ""
                }
            }
        } catch let error {
            print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return []
        }
    }
}
```

For me having the localizedDescription as error helped understand what went wrong with escaping, since it's displays which final regex swift tries to implement.

Answer (score 1):

basic phone number matching

```
let phoneNumbers = ["+79990001101", "+7 (800) 000-11-02", "+34 507 574 147 ", "+1-202-555-0118"]

let match: (String) -> String = {
    $0.replacingOccurrences(of: #"[^\d+]"#, with: "", options: .regularExpression)
}

print(phoneNumbers.map(match))
// ["+79990001101", "+78000001102", "+34507574147", "+12025550118"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `matching(regex:)` on the string like:

```
let array = try "Your String To Search".matching(regex: ".")
```

using this simple extension:

```
public extension String {
    func matching(regex: String) throws -> [String] {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex)
        let results = regex.matches(in: self, range: NSRange(startIndex..., in: self))
        return results.map { String(self[Range($0.range, in: self)!]) }
    }
}
```