# preg_match equivalent in Swift

Tags: php, regex, swift

I tried to translate a PHP function to Swift. The function is used to format a String to an other according the my regular expression. So here's what I do in PHP :

```
    preg_match('/P(([0-9]+)Y)?(([0-9]+)M)?(([0-9]+)D)?T?(([0-9]+)H)?(([0-9]+)M)?(([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]+)?S)?/', $duration, $matches)
```

I use the $matches array to format my new String.
So, in Swift, i found this thread : [Swift extract regex matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880650/swift-extract-regex-matches), which seems to do what I want. But when i get the result, my array is only one String long, with my entire input...

```
    func matchesForRegexInText(regex: String!, text: String!) -> [String] {

       let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex,
           options: nil, error: nil)!
       let nsString = text as NSString
       let results = regex.matchesInString(text,
       options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, nsString.length)) as    [NSTextCheckingResult]
       return map(results) { nsString.substringWithRange($0.range)}
    }

    let matches = matchesForRegexInText("P(([0-9]+)Y)?(([0-9]+)M)?(([0-9]+)D)?T?(([0-9]+)H)?(([0-9]+)M)?(([0-9]+)(.[0-9]+)?S)?", text: "PT00042H42M42S")
    println(matches)
    // [PT00042H42M42S]
```

Do you know what's wrong?

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array contains one element because the input contains exactly one string "PT00042H42M42S" which matches the pattern.

If you want to retrieve the matching *capture groups* then you have to
use `rangeAtIndex:` on the `NSTextCheckingResult`. Example:

```
let pattern = "P(([0-9]+)Y)?(([0-9]+)M)?(([0-9]+)D)?T?(([0-9]+)H)?(([0-9]+)M)?(([0-9]+)(.[0-9]+)?S)?"
let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: nil, error: nil)!
let text = "PT00042H42M42S"
let nsString = text as NSString
if let result = regex.firstMatchInString(text, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, nsString.length)) {
    for i in 0 ..< result.numberOfRanges {
        let range = result.rangeAtIndex(i)
        if range.location != NSNotFound {
            let substring = nsString.substringWithRange(result.rangeAtIndex(i))
            println("\(i): \(substring)")
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
0: PT00042H42M42S
7: 00042H
8: 00042
9: 42M
10: 42
11: 42S
12: 42
```

Comment: Just when you post I find the result with the library : https://github.com/johnno1962/SwiftRegex
Thank you for not letting me becoming crazy!