# NSRegularExpression Returns Invalid Range

Tags: regex, swift, cocoa, nsregularexpression

When I run the following code in a Playground, I get an invalid range as a result:

```
import Cocoa

var error: NSError?
var captureGroups: [String] = []
var input = "http://www.google.com"

var pattern = "(https?|ftp|file|gopher|mailto|news|nntp|telnet|wais)://[a-zA-Z0-9_@]+([.:][a-zA-Z0-9_@]+)*/?[a-zA-Z0-9_?,%#~&/\\-]+([:.][a-zA-Z0-9_?,%#~&/\\-]+)*"

var internalExpression = NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .CaseInsensitive, error: &error)!

if let match = internalExpression.firstMatchInString(input, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, count(input))) {

    match.numberOfRanges // 4
    match.rangeAtIndex(0) // (0, 21)
    match.rangeAtIndex(1) // (0, 4)
    match.rangeAtIndex(2) // (17, 3)
    match.rangeAtIndex(3) // (9223372036854775807,0)
}
```

This code has worked for other regular expressions, it seems to be only this one that is giving it trouble. I am not a RegEx expert, so I am unsure as to how I should proceed.

Comment: works here https://regex101.com/r/nK7oK0/2

Comment: 9223372036854775807 is NSIntegerMax aka NSNotFound, i.e. there is no match for the last capture group. What result do you expect?

Comment: @MartinR I would have expected the match to fail, but I am not a RegEx expert. Is there a preferred method to test for this case? I am relatively new to Cocoa as well.

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/30078306/1187415.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do an if test like this:

```
if match.rangeAtIndex(3).location != NSNotFound {
    // Do if found result.
} else {
    // Handle error.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to parse a URL, it's probably easiest to use `NSURL`:

```
if let url = NSURL(string: input) {
    println(url.scheme)
    println(url.host)
    println(url.path)
    println(url.pathComponents)
    println(url.query)
}
```

If you want help fixing the regex and understanding why you received `NSNotFound`, you should clearly describe what you were hoping to parse out of it. But when dealing with URLs, `NSURL` is easiest.