# iOS Swift Regular expression, how to match a string?

Tags: ios, regex, swift

I am new to Swift and I want to make some regex to check if a string matches with a certain pattern.

I have this URL:

```
http://server.com/folder/image_09.jpg
```

URL can also be:

```
http://server.com/folder/image.jpg
```

And I want to check if the string matches this pattern:

```
sometext + _two characters + .jpg
```

Comment: What regex did you try? What were the results? What specific part of the regex is blocking you?

Comment: Also tried this: ".+_/w{2}[.]jpg"

Comment: ICU User Guide: [Regular Expressions](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your search pattern could be `"_\w{2}\.jpg$"`

```
let regExp = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "_\\w{2}\\.jpg$", options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive, error: nil)
let urlString = "http://www.foo.it/image_00.jpg"
let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: count(urlString.utf16))
if let numberMatches = regExp?.numberOfMatchesInString(urlString, options: NSMatchingOptions(0), range: range)
    where numberMatches == 1 {
        let s = "OK"
} else {
    let s = "No matches found"
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: `count(urlString.utf8)` should be `(urlString as NSString).length` or `count(urlString.utf16)`, otherwise it crashes for strings containing non-ASCII characters, e.g. `urlString = "http://www.foo.it/äöüimage_00.jpg"` . Compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/27880748/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR Edited. Didn't think about it since commonly urls comes from utf8 encoded pages. Thanks