# Convert hexcode of currency symbol to string in swift3

Tags: swift3

i am having the hexValue of $ like string and i have searched that is it equivalent of $ so how can i convert it to $ ?

i have searched this thing but it not what i want
[Converting Hex String to NSData in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26501276/converting-hex-string-to-nsdata-in-swift)

Comment: This could help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31817292/2043580

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by doing this

```
let str = symbol
        if let htmldata = str.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8), let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: htmldata, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
        {
            let finalString = String(format: "%@",attributedString.string)
            return finalString
        }
        else
        {
            return ""
        }
```