# I got question mark when font awesome swift5

Tags: ios, swift, font-awesome

when I use a font awesome in swift I get just question mark even when I use different hex code like f002 , f4d7 and etc in u{}.

I also add property Font provided by application in info.plist

so what's your idea to solve it.  in the below photo I put every think you may need to know  :

[image]

[image]

Comment: You didn't show the info plist and you didn't prove that the font is added to the target.

Comment: @matt thank u for attention our best iOS teacher around the world , I updated and I show my info.plist

Answer (score 1):

1: check your font

```
for family in UIFont.familyNames {
    print("\(family)")

    for name in UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: family) {
        print("\(name)")
    }
}
```

2: maybe you have to use
[Hex string to text conversion - swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42753173/hex-string-to-text-conversion-swift-3)

Comment: yes it was a good idea I have a list of string fonts like , Helvetica , Times New Roman and etc but how could I recognise it is font awesome and access hexes in that?

Comment: does it contain your font?

Comment: and try it.
categoryLbl.text = "\u{1F431}"

Comment: no it doesn't , because name of the fonts are like default font of Xcode

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/text_display_and_fonts/adding_a_custom_font_to_your_app
read it

Comment: thank you brother yes I got result and also we can follow this link too : https://medium.com/@umairhassanbaig/ios-how-to-use-font-awesome-in-xcode-project-b8ef255973a3