# Finding text between parentheses in Swift

Tags: regex, string, swift

How do you get an array of string values for the text between parentheses in Swift?

For example from: `MyFileName(2015)(Type)(createdBy).zip`

I would like:  `[2015,Type,createdBy]`

Comment: I believe the term you're looking for is "parentheses". ;-)

Comment: @Thomas: You should post your comment as an answer. Bonus points if you elaborate it with a Swift / Cocoa regex example. :-)

Comment: if I use that Reg Ex in Swift I get a compile error, say from the answer in the swift 2 link by @ConradoCostal I use the function suggested and then try `let matches = matchesForRegexInText("\((.*?)\)", text: string)`  I get expected separator error after the . and if I try to do this: `let regEx = "\((.*?)\)"` I get invalid character in source error.

Comment: @KevinMann This regex string conflicts with Swift's syntactic sugar for String interpolation. You have to escape each \ character with another \ to make it work.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a complete example in Swift 4.2

```
func matchesForRegexInText(regex: String!, text: String!) -> [String] {

do {

    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex, options: [])
    let nsString = text as NSString

    let results = regex.matches(in: text,
                                        options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, nsString.length))
    return results.map { nsString.substring(with: $0.range)}

} catch let error as NSError {

    print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")

    return []
}}
```

and usage :

```
let regex = "\\((.*?)\\)"
mmatchesForRegexInText(regex: regex, text: " exmaple (android) of (qwe123) text (heart) between parentheses")
```

Comment: The function looks like a verbatim copy from https://stackoverflow.com/a/27880748/1187415.

Answer (score 4):

Just updating the chosen answer to Swift 3:

```
func matchesForRegexInText(regex: String!, text: String!) -> [String] {

do {

    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex, options: [])
    let nsString = text as NSString

    let results = regex.matches(in: text,
                                        options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, nsString.length))
    return results.map { nsString.substring(with: $0.range)}

} catch let error as NSError {

    print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")

    return []
}}
```

The usage remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex for this

[Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2754599/thomas) had a good example: `\((.*?)\)`

How to use a regex with Swift you can look up at: http://www.raywenderlich.com/86205/nsregularexpression-swift-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Here is my RegEx
which is actually trying to get the words between parentheses. E.g. (smile)

```
NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\\\(\\\w+\\\\)",options:NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive)
```

it works for me!