# Regex match group

Tags: regex, match

How to match multiple times a group using a simple regex. I try with this: `(?:key:)((?:\s*'[^']+'))`, but does not work.

Input

key: 'val1' 'val2' 'val3'

Output

group 1 = val1

group 2 = val2

group 3 = val3

**EDIT:** How to find all tags enclosed by simples quotes after a desired key?

Comment: maybe duplicated with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003623/how-to-capture-multiple-repeated-groups

Comment: that do not solve my problem

Comment: Post an example of what the result should be. Also explain the search pattern as best as you can. Like when you say, "group"... a group of what?

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly do what you want. With regex you can't have a variable number of capturing groups.

However. If your amount of groups is limited, then you could repeat `(?:\s*('[^']+')*)?` for that limit. Thus to be able to match your given example, you'd need.

```
key:(?:\s*('[^']+')*)?(?:\s*('[^']+')*)?(?:\s*('[^']+')*)?
```

*Note that `(?:\s*('[^']+')*)?` has been repeated 3 times.*

[**Live preview**](https://regex101.com/r/pJ4Uw9/1)

It might be easier and better to just iterate over this pattern `'[^']+'`. As you didn't mention any language, I took the liberty of doing it in Python.

```
import re
string = "'val1' 'val2' 'val3'"
for i, match in enumerate(re.finditer(r"'([^']+)'", string), start=1):
    print("group %d = %s" % (i, match.group(1)))
```

The above when executed will print:

> group 1 = val1
>
> group 2 = val2
>
> group 3 = val3

So instead of trying to make a "variable" number of capturing groups. Instead try an iterate all the matches for the quotes pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using the following regular expression: `(?:key:\G)|('[^']+')+`, [here](https://regex101.com/r/btiVeq/2) is the link to check how it works.