# regex: HTML tag containing all attributes

Tags: html, regex

I want to match HTML tags and its containing attributes. Tried the following [regex](https://regex101.com/r/IPGxzs/1):

```
/<(\w+)(?: +(\w+)="[\w,;.:\-#'+~*?=&%\$!\/'\]\[@\(\)\s]*")*/gm
```

On that input:

```
<p><li first="1" second="2" third="3"></li><b><br/><p><li first="1" second="2" third="3"></li><b><br/></p>
<p><li first="1" second="2"></li><b><br/><p><li first="1" second="2"></li><b><br/></p>
<p><li first="1"></li><b><br/><p><li first="1"></li><b><br/></p>
```

I only get one attribute. If there are more than one attributes in a tag, I always get the last one. First row returns `third`, second row returns `second` and last row returns `first` for `group 2`.

The result is for line number one is:

```
p li third b br p li third b br
```

But should be:

```
p li first second third b br p li first second third b br
```

How do I get all attributes to a tag?

Comment: Why not use something like the [HTML agility pack?](https://html-agility-pack.net/)

Comment: [Have you tried using an XML parser instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454)

Comment: I'm not allowed to use any package or tool except regex to get that problem solved.

Comment: [TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3343753), why don't you use an HTML parser?

Comment: @Pedro Rodrigues thank you for that great link! My example was a school exercise and only regex was allowed. In projects I still use HTML parser and lib tools to get that solved :)

Comment: @Chris, you're welcome. For future reference, if it is homework, please note that on your questions. Most times people will be able to notice it, giving it away from the gecko will give the best result on stackoverflow.

Comment: what a bad exercise, tell that to your teacher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I think you can use `[^"]` instead of `[\w,;.:\-#'+~*?=&%\$!\/'\]\[@\(\)\s]`

Unfortunately with regex it is not possible to capture all of the arguments in your case. Fur further explanation see this post: [How to capture multiple repeated groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003623/how-to-capture-multiple-repeated-groups)

Comment: Great, that I'll try it with more steps.