# Python regex for capturing comma-separated strings conditionally

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of person names which can have 3 different styles:

1. `{last name}, {first name} {middle name}` (Example: Bob, Dylan Tina)
2. `{last name}, {first name} {middle initial}.` (Example: Bob, Dylan T.)
3. `{last name}, {first name}` (Example: Bob, Dylan)

And this is the regex which I wrote:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+(([' ,.-][a-zA-Z ])?[a-zA-Z]*)*$
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to capture multiple repeated groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003623/how-to-capture-multiple-repeated-groups)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write the regex like this

```
^(\w+),\s(\w+)\s*(\w*\.?)$
```

Here is the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/JG8S8J/3/).

Update the regex to like this and you can get three different groups for your three cases

```
^(\w+,\s\w+\s\w+)$|^(\w+,\s\w+\s\w+\.)$|^(\w+,\s\w+)$
```

Here is the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/JG8S8J/4).

Here is the python code

```
import re
s2 = "Bob, Dylan"
out = re.findall(r"^(\w+),\s(\w+)\s*(\w*\.?)$",s2)
print(out)
```

OUTPUT

```
[('Bob', 'Dylan', '')]
```

Comment: Is it possible to write regex for each case separately?

Comment: @user8714896 Yes it is possible.

Comment: This will return `[('Bob', 'Dyla', 'n')]` for `re.findall(p, "Bob, Dylan")`.

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasimazar which one are you taking about ?

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasimazar It works alright in the demo. Sorry,  *talking about, i made a typo above.

Comment: I was talking about your first suggested regex Albin; `^(\w+),\s(\w+)\s*(\w*\.?)$`.

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasimazar it works fine for me. I just tested it in python script. I don't know the reason why it is not working for you.

Comment: What is your python version and the python code that you are using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203882/discussion-between-albin-paul-and-zeinab-abbasimazar).

Answer (score 0):

You should use this regex:

```
(\w+),\s*(\w+)\s*(\w{0,}\.*)
```

This is the result you'll get:

```
>>> import re
>>> s1 = "Bob, Dylan Tina"
>>> s2 = "Bob, Dylan"
>>> s3 = "Bob, Dylan T."
>>> p = re.compile(r"(\w+),\s*(\w+)\s*(\w{0,}\.*)")
>>> re.findall(p, s1)
[('Bob', 'Dylan', 'Tina')]
>>> re.findall(p, s2)
[('Bob', 'Dylan', '')]
>>> re.findall(p, s3)
[('Bob', 'Dylan', 'T.')]
```