# Why isn't this repeated inner group matching in regex?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to parse the following LaTeX string:

```
\graphicspath{
  {outputs/tikz/turnover/}
  {outputs/tikz/health/}
  {outputs/tikz/flows/}
  {outputs/model/figs/compare/}
  {outputs/model/figs/sensitivity/}
  {outputs/model/figs/flows/}
}
```

My regex (python) is: `'\\graphicspath\{\s*?(\{.*?\}\s*?)*\}'` (with Global & Multiline flags),
which I thought would collect the 6 different paths.
Instead, only the last group is matched by the inner group: `{outputs/model/figs/flows/}`.

Why aren't the other paths matched? It seems like the non-greedy `*?` within the `{ }` is being more greedy than the `*` outside the group, which is supposed to repeat the group. Thanks,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003623/how-to-capture-multiple-repeated-groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All paths are matched with a repeated group pattern, but only the last one is stored as group value.

You can either change the regex to extract all paths in one group using non capturing group `(?:)`

```
\\graphicspath\{\s*?((?:\{.*?\}\s*?)*)\}
```

or `re.findall` / `re.finditer` all paths inside brackets with this regex:

```
^\s.*{\S*}$
```

Comment: Amazing -- thanks! I didn't know that capturing and non-capturing groups had different sub-group behaviour.

Comment: Nice answer! :)