# How to write a Ruby script that extracts IPs from a NMAP scan

Tags: regex, ruby, scripting, nmap

I'm trying to write a script in Ruby that extracts some IP and different informations from a NMAP scan output. I'm using regular expressions and I already know how to properly extract IPs but there's something I'm not fully understanding with the grouping concept.

Let's say I have the current string in the file and I want to extract the IP value:

> "Nmap scan report for 10.50.96.1"

Here I'm playing around with *pry* and building my script to recognize IP:

```
>> string = "Nmap scan report for 10.50.96.1"
=> "Nmap scan report for 10.50.96.1"
>> test = /(\d{1,3}\.){3}/.match(string)
=> #<MatchData "10.50.96." 1:"96.">
```

I do not understand why the global variable `$1` is set as `96.`.

Shouldn't I have 3 groups, with the 3 values `10.`, `50.` and `96.`?

Comment: Probably, you need `test = /(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})/.match(string)`. Repeated capturing groups only "save" the last value captured.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ok right, every set of parenthesis is a single group. But why I only have 96. set as a group?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003623/how-to-capture-multiple-repeated-groups

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ok, thought about it but it seemed a strange behavior in the first place. Thanks!