# Match strict syntax for multiple quoted strings delimited by comma

Tags: java, regex

How to match the whole ("SOMETHING","SOMETHING","SOMETHING",...) expression(only quoted upper case A-Z characters without special symbols and whitespaces) and group quoted strings?

```
("JOY","SAD") - should match
("JOY","sad") - shouldn't match
("JOY",0) - shouldn't match
("JOY","'")- shouldn't match
("JOY",SAD) - shouldn't match
("JOY","") - shouldn't match
("") - shouldn't match
("0") - shouldn't match
(a) - shouldn't match
```

Tried this regex expression - it groups it correct but still some examples are passed:

```
\((\"([A-Z]+)*\")\)
```

**UPDATE**

Used suggested regex by @anubhava a little bit modifying match group - `(?:\(|\G(?!^),)\"([A-Z]+)\"(?=(?:,\"[A-Z]+\")*\)$)` in java Pattern.compile:

```
Pattern.compile("(?:^\\(|\\G(?!^),)(\\\"[A-Z]+\\\")(?=(?:,\\\"[A-Z]+\\\")*\\)$)")
```

However, why the same regex expression cannot be matched if I use java Patter.compile() method?

Comment: `\(\"[A-Z]+\"(?:,\"[A-Z]+\")*\)`? See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TzSWo5/2)

Comment: It matches first example but it doesn't group all string in quotes(it groups only first string in quotes).

Comment: Also, see [How to capture multiple repeated groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003623/) In PCRE, you would use something like `(?:\G(?!^),|^\((?=\"[A-Z]+\"(?:,\"[A-Z]+\")*\)$))\K\"[A-Z]+\"`, see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ndn62J/1).

Comment: I use this platform - https://regex101.com/ . I just cannot understand how to combine input validation and string grouping. Also amount of quoted strings might be different from 1 to 10 quoted strings in parentheses. I need to validate the whole input and then extract all strings from quotes.

Comment: @ViktorV.: See this regex demo: https://regex101.com/r/Fob7Xq/1

Comment: @anubhava Your regex expression works fine in regex101.com platform but why the same regex couldn't match in java Pattern.compile method?

Comment: @ViktorV.: Are you using Java?

Comment: @anubhava Yes, correct. Tried your regex expr with escaped symbols: 
Pattern.compile("(?:^\\(|\\G(?!^),)(\\\"[A-Z]+\\\")(?=(?:,\\\"[A-Z]+\\\")*\\)$)")

Comment: I have posted a detailed answer below with Java code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on discussion in comments section, you may use this regex using `\G` for validating and retrieving individual groups:

```
(?:^\(|\G(?!^),)("[A-Z]+")(?=(?:,"[A-Z]+")*\)$)
```

- `\G` asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match.
- `\G(?!^)`: Make sure `\G` is not matched at line start
- `(?=(?:,"[A-Z]+")*\)$)`: Positive lookahead to assert that we have zero or more quoted strings ahead using comma delimiter.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Fob7Xq/1)

**Java Code:**

```
final String str = "(\"JOY\",\"SAD\")";
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
                   "(?:^\\(|\\G(?!^),)(\"[A-Z]+\")(?=(?:,\"[A-Z]+\")*\\)$)");
Matcher m = p.matcher( str );

while ( m.find() ) {
    System.out.println( m.group(1) );
}
```

**Output:**

```
"JOY"
"SAD"
```

Comment: Thanks for explanatory answer! Hm, I got what is confused me a lot. I used Pattern.compile(...).matcher(...).matches() where matches() returns false by some reason. In your example the same result for this method. However, find() method find all strings that I need.