# Extract coordinates from a string regex

Tags: python, regex, coordinates

I am trying to extract coordinates of various formats from reddit comments. I want to be able to extract the two different coordinate formats supported on google maps:

`73.180633, -98.100802` and `73°10'50.3"N 98°06'02.9"W`

I am able to extract coordinates in the first format with this expression:

`([-+]?\d{1,2}[.]\d+),\s*([-+]?\d{1,3}[.]\d+)`

However, I have not been able to successfully find or make a pattern to match the second format.

Comment: Show sample reddit comment...

Answer (score 1):

This will do it for the second format: `\d{1,3}°\d{1,3}'\d{1,3}\.\d\"[N|S]\s\d{1,3}°\d{1,3}'\d{1,3}\.\d\"[E|W]`

See: https://regex101.com/r/LN1igj/8

There are two very similar groups, apparently it's not possible to simplify that. See [How to capture multiple repeated groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003623/how-to-capture-multiple-repeated-groups).

To capture both formats in one regex: `(?:((?:[-+]?\d{1,2}[.]\d+),\s*(?:[-+]?\d{1,3}[.]\d+))|(\d{1,3}°\d{1,3}'\d{1,3}\.\d\"[N|S]\s\d{1,3}°\d{1,3}'\d{1,3}\.\d\"[E|W]))`

See: https://regex101.com/r/LN1igj/7

But this is not really readable anymore. I would advice to solve that in code.

Comment: Happy to help. Thx for accepting the answer and upvoting it.

Comment: Longitude goes from -180 to +180.  So I think at least one of your {2}'s needs to be {2,3}

Comment: Is there a way I can combine my two expressions into a single one? I tried using an or (exp1 | exp2)  but that did not work. Neither format matched

Comment: @ChristianBaumann doesn't seem to work for `36°10'13.6"N 115°08'23.6"W`, tested using the combined expression

Comment: @rgmcode Updated: `(?:((?:[-+]?\d{1,2}[.]\d+),\s*(?:[-+]?\d{1,3}[.]\d+))|(\d{2,3}°\d{2}'\d{2,3}\.\d\"[N|S]\s\d{2,3}°\d{2}'\d{2,3}\.\d\"[E|W]))` https://regex101.com/r/LN1igj/4

Comment: @rgmcode What are valid ranges for the 4 numbers: `[1]°[2]'[3].[4]"N` ?

Comment: @ChristianBaumann the first term <=90 for latitude, <=180 for longitude, I think everything else should be <=60, It seems like the pattern fails to match when the longitude degree term is >=100

Answer (score 0):

- Latitudes are represented from 90S 90N and longitudes are represented from 0 to 180.
- Apart from seconds, Degrees and minutes also can have decimal points instead of further sub units.
- It can also be represented as just decimal numbers with +/-

Please try below regex.

```regex
(^| )(-?\d{1,2}(\.\d+)?(?=\s*,?\s*)[\s,]+-?\d{1,3}(\.\d+)?|\d{1,2}(\.\d+°|°(\d{1,2}(\.\d+'|'(\d{1,2}(\.\d+)?\")?))?)[NS](?=\s*,?\s*)[\s,]+\d{1,3}(\.\d+°|°(\d{1,2}(\.\d+'|'(\d{1,2}(\.\d+)?\")?))?)[EW])
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LN1igj/10)

Comment: thank you! This worked on other formats as well such as those on google earth (which uses different dms and decimal than maps for some reason) which is super useful