# Regex ignore match when found string

Tags: php, regex, autohotkey

I wrote this Regex to match any string before a `.= or = or :=`

How I could also add to if on the same line exists the word `foo` it then did not match anything in that line?

https://regex101.com/r/tJRoDh/213

`(?!.*foo)\b(\w+)\s*(\.=|=|:=)`

```
x = foo 
foo x= 
x = foo 
foo text :=
text := x text foo

^ don't match any of these because exist the word foo on the same line
---------------------------------------------

text HELLO:= text text
     ^ match hello
text x = text 
     ^ match x
text .= something else y:= color 
^ match text           ^ match y
```

I'm using the regex on AutoHotkey to match all strings before `.= = and :=`

Comment: Sure, i will, btw your pattern did match this line `foo text :=` it contains foo, should not had caught it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word)

Comment: I'm a beginner in regex I don't know how to combine two regex on one

Comment: Match any string before a `.= or = or :=` but if on the same line exist the word foo then on that line doesn't match anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoHotKey refers to the pcre manual at the [regex quick reference](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/RegEx-QuickRef.htm)

In that case, to get the multiple matches, you could make use of the `\G` anchor which asserts the position at the end of the previous match of at the start of the string for the first match.

```
\G(?!.*\bfoo\b)[^.:=\r\n]*(?:[.:](?!=)[^.:=\r\n]*)*\b(\w+)\h*([.:]?=)
```

**Explanation**

- `\G` Assert the position at the end of the previous match or in this case at the start of the string
- `(?!.*\bfoo\b)` Negative lookahead, assert that the string does not contain `foo`
- `[^.:=\r\n]*` Match 0+ times any char except `.` `:` `=` or a newline
- `(?:[.:](?!=)[^.:=\r\n]*)*` If it does encounter a `.` or `:` only match it when it is not directly followed by `=` and repeat this 0+ times in case this happens multiple times
- `\b(\w+)` Word boundary, capture 1+ word chars in group 1
- `\h*([.:]?=)` Match 0+ horizontal whitespace chars and capture in group 2 either `.=` `:=` or `=`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/q0NTXW/1)

Answer (score 1):

The following regex seems sufficient:

```
^(?:(?!foo).)*\b(\w+)\s*(\.=|=|:=)(?:(?!foo).)*$
```

This uses the canonical [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word) before and after the desired substring pattern, thus rejecting lines with the substring `"foo"` before or after the target.

Comment: on the last line text was not caught, its before an `.=`

Comment: I see. Capture groups only store the last result so use `preg_match_all` to extract everything programmatically. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003623/how-to-capture-multiple-repeated-groups). There might be a clever way to do it, but I'd probably apply one regex to filter out `foo` lines, then a second to extract the assignment substrings you're interested in.

Comment: I have read the link you post but I did not understand how to apply it to your regex

Comment: How are you actually using this regex in your code?

Comment: im using it on autohotkey to catch all declared variables as they are before .=  or = or :=
`regex = Om)\b(\w+)\s*(\.=|=|:=)
Matches := RegExMatchAll(sourceB,regex)
for i,v in Matches {
 z := v.value[1]
 variables.push(z)
}`

Comment: Please update your post with that code and context.

Comment: I don't see any code in there. What language is this? It doesn't look like PHP to me--probably Golang or something? I'm not sure how to get multiple matches and reject `foo` in one pattern but maybe someone else knows. Until then, I'd just apply two regexes as suggested above. Once you have a matching line it's pretty easy to get all matches from a line with your original regex `/\b(\w+)\s*(\.=|=|:=)/m`. I can offer an example if you can specify the lang you're using with some basic boilerplate.