# Regex trouble with capturing repeated pattern

Tags: php, regex, pcre

Lets say I have the following string:

`Some crap string here...(TRACK "title1" F (S #h88 (P #m6) (P #m31)) (S #k3 (P #m58) (P #m58)))(TRACK "title2" P (S #a54 (P #r8)) (S #v59 (P #a25) (P #y82)))...Some other crap string here`

Out of this string I need to extract to following data:

1. title1
2. F
3. (S #h88 (P #m6) (P #m31)) and (S #k3 (P #m58) (P #m58))

and

1. title2
2. P
3. (S #a54 (P #r8)) and (S #v59 (P #a25) (P #y82))

where

1. is some kind of title.
2. is some kind of status.
3. is some kind of list of lists, like `(S #xx (P #xx))`.

Having limited regex knowledge, I can get 1 and 2, but only get the first part of 3.
`(S #xx (P #xx))` can exist multiple times and also the inner (P #xx) can exist multiple times.

I've tried many regex expression and consulted a lot of posts, but I keep having troubles getting the data out as requested.

So now I'm back at `\(TRACK "(.*?)" ([P|F]) (\(S.*?\)\))` which only captures the first of two lists in this example string.

see: https://regex101.com/r/FM0ZZR/1

What do I need to do to get all lists as described?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```php
\(TRACK\s+"([^"]*)"\s+([PF])((?:\s+(\([SP](?:[^()]*+|(?-1))*\)))*\))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PusvWB/3/).

*Details*

- `\(TRACK` - a `(TRACK` substring
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `"` - a `"` char
- `([^"]*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than `"`
- `"` - a `"` char
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `([PF])` - Group 2: `P` or `F`
- `((?:\s+(\([SP](?:[^()]*+|(?-1))*\)))*\))` - Group 3:

  - `(?:\s+(\([SP](?:[^()]*+|(?-1))*\)))*` - zero or more repetitions of

    - `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
    - `(\([SP](?:[^()]*+|(?-1))*\))` - Group 4 (technical, necessary for recursion):

      - `\(` - a `(` char
      - `[SP]` - `S` or `P`
      - `(?:[^()]*+|(?-1))*` - zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` or the whole most recently captured pattern
      - `\)` - a `)` char
  - `\)` - a `)` char.

Comment: Thank you very much, but unfortunately, this regex does not capture the first (S #xx (P #xx)) of each match.E.g. (S #h88 (P #m6) (P #m31))

Comment: @DigiLive It does capture it, but since it is a [repeated capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003623/how-to-capture-multiple-repeated-groups), only the last value is kept in the group memory buffer. You cannot access each separate capture using a PCRE pattern as it has no support for a capturing group stack. You could write it like [this](https://regex101.com/r/PusvWB/4), `(?:\G(?!\A)|\(TRACK\s+"([^"]*)"\s+([PF]))\s+(\([SP](?:[^()]*+|(?-1))*\))\)?`, but it will not be quite usable, or will require quite a lot of extra code.

Comment: Cool recursing the subpattern with `(?-1)`, those patterns are awesome ++