# What regex to split a dot delimited string into arbitrary number of capture groups

Tags: regex

I would like to separate a dot delimited string into its component parts using regex.

I can build something that captures the first example, but struggling to find out how to get the pattern to recurse.

The source string is something like

```
all.cats.like.chicken
```

I would like the output to be (in this case) four capture groups

```
1: all
2: cats
3: like
4: chicken
```

I have this pattern that will return the first and second elements

```
(/\w*)(?:\.(\w*)) (i.e. 1:all 2:cats)
```

And this version will return the first and last elements

```
(\w*)(?:\.(\w*))+ (i.e. 1:all 2:chicken)
```

How do I modify (or replace!) this to get all the terms?

Thanks in advance for whatever help you can provide.

Comment: Specifically, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59204121/3832970) if all you have is just a regex pattern and no code (the regex will look like [this](https://regex101.com/r/rkxuHz/1) then.) But if you can, simply split with a dot.

Comment: Thank you! I tried searching for the answer you linked to but did not find it.  Your help much appreciated.