# Regex: Extract individual words between XML (angled) tags

Tags: regex, xml

I have an XML payload and I'm trying to form a regex pattern to use in a global search and replace. The XML payload looks like:

```
<NODE1>A1</NODE1>
<NODE2>B1  B2 B3 B4 </NODE2>
<NODE3>C1</NODE3>
```

I'm looking to extract the text between the `NODE2` tags to individually capture "B1", "B2", "B3" and "B4". The amount of white-space between each "word" varies.

I can capture the entire text easily enough (`(?<=NODE2>)(.*)(?=<\/NODE2)`), or the first "word" (`(?<=NODE2>)(\S+).*(?=<\/NODE2)`), but can't seem to find a working example of capturing each word individually between the tags. Any help much appreciated.

EDIT:

- The XML payload is, other than white space variations, as per the example and produced consistently by a single process. There are no node attributes or angled brackets in the node value.
- This is a one time use case, I have a series of payloads that were used for testing that need to be updated to a new format. The payloads as a whole are hard to regenerate in the new format.
- I am using VSCode to do the global search and replace. It's been able to easily solve all the other updates I have had to do, this is the last one and I think coding a solution is unnecessary in this scenario - the right pattern will solve this problem.

Comment: You are trying to capture a repeated group, which has been discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003623/how-to-capture-multiple-repeated-groups. In short, you will always get the last matched value for the capturing group.

There does not seem to be a feasible way to handle this only with RegEx. I would suggest you just extract the middle string and later split the string with string manipulation functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Caution with regex and XML parsing

It's always a bit dangerous to use regular expression to capture data in XML. Typically the `<NODE2>` tags could be written `< node2   >` or `<NODE2 id="3425">` and would be valid XML. The regular expression with the positive lookahead and lookbehind would not work as they often have to be fixed length.

If your XML is safe of changes then you could use this:

```
/(?<=NODE2>)\s*(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s*(?=<\/NODE2)/gi
```

You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/Bsul9m/2

I added the `i` case-insensitive flag in case the XML contains `<node2>` instead of `<NODE2>`.

You want to capture words so I used the `\w+` pattern. But this doesn't include special characters. So you could replace it by something else such as `\p{L}` to match any letter of any language and also add the digits with `\d` or `[0-9]`.

This was to reply to your question with the minimum of changes.

### Now, a better regex to work with XML without using a parser

This time, I will not use your lookahead and lookbehind patterns as it doesn't matter if we capture more as we are capturing your 4 items in any case.

We want to be able to match tags such as these:

- case insensitive: `<node2>`, `<Node2>` or `<NODE2>`.
- optional spaces: `< NODE2>`, `< node2   >...< / node2>`.
- optional attributes: `<node2 attribute="value" id="something">`.
- optional namespace: `<my-namespace:node2 id="123">`

This leeds to a regex more flexible:

```
/<\s*((?:[\w-]+:)?)node2\b[^>]*>\s*(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s*<\s*\/\s*\1node2\s*>/gi
```

You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/j6Bcbs/1

The advantage of this one is that it will be a bit more flexible with the XML structure. It works with the following:

```xml
<NODE1>A1</NODE1>
<NODE2 id="1234" title="Second node">B1  B2 B3 B4 </ NODE2 >
< node2>A1 B2 C3 ZZZ4</node2>
<namespace:node2>A1  A2 A3  A4</namespace:node2>
< other-namespace:node2 attr = "value"> W X Y Z</other-namespace:node2>
<NODE3>C1</NODE3>
```

You'll have the 4 items in the captured group 2 to 5. This is because the namespace is captured in the first group as it has to be identical in the closing tag.

Explained:

- `<\s*` matches the opening tag and optional spaces.
- `((?:[\w-]+:)?)` is the first capturing group to get an optional namespace (it's not 100% valid but will work in most cases). So this will capture `namespace:` or `other-namespace:` in the example above.
- `node2\b[^>]*>` will match *node2* with a word ending and then zero or multiple characters which are not closing tag then followed by a closing tag.
- `\s*(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s*` is the 4 capturing groups (index 2 to 5) for your 4 items you want to get. They can be surounded by spaces and have to be separated by spaces.
- `<\s*\/\s*\1node2\s*>` is the closing tag with a backreference to the capturing group 1 which is the optional namespace.

Answer (score 1):

If the `\G` anchor is supported and there can not be `<` and `>` in between, you could use a capture group

```
(?:<NODE2>|\G(?!^))\s*(\S+)(?=[^<>]*</NODE2>)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `<NODE2>` Match literally
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the position at the end of the previous match, not at the start
- `)` Close non capture group
- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars
- `(\S+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ non whitespace chars
- `(?=[^<>]*</NODE2>)` Positive lookahead, assert no occurrences of `<` or `>` at the right, followed by matching `</NODE2>`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/H5Je4d/1)

A bit more flexible variation:

```
(?:<[^>]*\bNODE2\b[^>]*>|\G(?!^))\s*([^<>\s]+)(?=[^>]*</[^>]*\bNODE2\s*>)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BJ7vCq/1)

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to process XML using regular expressions. For reasons, see for example here:

[Why it's not possible to use regex to parse HTML/XML: a formal explanation in layman's terms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la/50831919#50831919)

This problem is very easily solved in XPath. Using the current version (3.1) it's simply `//NODE2 ! tokenize(.)`.

Comment: I'm not processing/parsing the XML, I'm fixing it up so it can be parsed

Comment: "Fixing it up" sounds like processing to me. My advice stands - our workload on SO helping people with XML problems would be halved if people didn't attempt to parse and serialize XML by hand without knowing all the rules.