# How can I use regex to validate an inputed string similarly to this outlined structure?

Tags: regex

The structure I want the regex to validate in looks similar to this:

```js
keyword input(param_input,param_input2)
```

The "keyword" section needs to be built into the regex so it's not considered an input.

The **input**, **param_input** and **param_input2** can be letters(including caps), numbers and _, but none of these inputs can be entirely numbers.

What would be the best approach for writing a regex string to validate a string?

Attempt:

```js
function+\s+[a-zA-Z0-9]+((?!.*[,]{2})(?!.*[,0-9]{2})(?!^$,{1})[a-zA-Z0-9,]*)
```

Comment: Can you please share your attempt?

Comment: A warning: while a regex for simple comma-separated tokens is easy and can work well, things get much more complicated if you also want to allow strings that include a comma, like in `keyword myinput(myparam1, "string1,string2")`. In that case, a regex is not the ideal solution.

Comment: @cornuz I don't at the moment want to allow " in the inputs

Comment: @hiteshbedre function+\s+[a-zA-Z0-9]+\((?!.*[,]{2})(?!.*[,0-9]{2})(?!^$,{1})[a-zA-Z0-9,]*\)

Comment: Assuming you're matching code, most languages don't allow identifiers to start with a digit, so the terms would be either all digits `\d+` or `(?=\D)\w+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *negative lookahead assertions* to make sure that the characters you are capturing isn't purely digits. Try this:

```
^[\w]+ (?!\d+\()([\w]+)\((?:(?!\d+[,\)])(\w+)),(?:(?!\d+[,\)])(\w+))\)$
```

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/Zt014P/4).

```
keyword input(param_input,param_input2)  -> Will match
keyword 12345(param_input,param_input2)
keyword in123(abc123_DEF4,a1_b2_C3_d45)  -> Will match
keyword input(12345678901,param_input2)
keyword input(param_input,123456789012)
keyword input(12345678901,123456789012)
keyword XYZ98(aaaa1111BB2,CCCCCCC33333)  -> Will match
keyword XYZ98(aaaa1111BB2,CCCCCCC33333,DD44)
```

Where:

- `^[\w]+`  - Match the initial string e.g. `keyword`
- `(?!\d+\()([\w]+)\(` - Using a negative lookahead assertion, match the next part until `(`  **only if** it isn't purely digits e.g. `input(` but not `12345(`
- `(?:(?!\d+[,\)])(\w+)),` - Again using a negative lookahead assertion, match the next part until `,`  **only if** it isn't purely digits e.g. `param_input,` but not `12345678901,`
- `(?:(?!\d+[,\)])(\w+))\)$` - Again using a negative lookahead assertion, match the next part until the ending `)`  **only if** it isn't purely digits e.g. `param_input2)` but not `123456789012))`

This is fixed to 2x input parameters e.g. `(param_input,param_input2)`. Note that if you wish to accept variable amount of input parameters e.g. `(param1,param2,param3,...,paramN)`, you can't easily do it with regex groups as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37004214/11043825) from another thread.

- What you can do instead is manually define this `(?:(?!\d+[,\)])(\w+)),` for every additional parameter.

---

References:

- https://www.ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/and-in-regex/