# Regex group doesn't capture all of matched part of string

Tags: python, regex

I have the following regex: `'(/[a-zA-Z]+)*/([a-zA-Z]+)\.?$'`.

Given a string the following string "/foo/bar/baz", I expect the first captured group to be "/foo/bar". However, I get the following:

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile('(/[a-zA-Z]+)*/([a-zA-Z]+)\.?$');
>>> match = regex.match('/foo/bar/baz')
>>> match.group(1)
'/bar'
```

Why isn't the whole expected group being captured?

Edit: It's worth mentioning that the strings I'm trying to match are parts of URLs. To give you an idea, it's the part of the URL that would be returned from `window.location.pathname` in javascript, only without file extensions.

Comment: What are you trying to extract here and what is the logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will capture multiple repeated groups:

```
(/[a-zA-Z]+)*
```

However, as already discussed in another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003623/how-to-capture-multiple-repeated-groups), quoting from @ByteCommander

> If your capture group gets repeated by the pattern (you used the + quantifier on the surrounding non-capturing group), **only the last value that matches it gets stored**.

Thus the reason why you are only seeing the last match `"/bar"`. What you can do instead is take advantage of the greedy matching of `.*` up to the last `/` via the pattern `(/.*)/`

```
regex = re.compile('(/.*)/([a-zA-Z]+)\.?$');
```

Comment: This mostly answers my question. Wouldn't `(/.*)/` match any characters? For example, `'/_&@!@#%/'` would match. What do I do if I want to use greedy matching but only match certain characters?

Comment: Greedy matching works by matching up to the last possible character **BUT** still satisfying the whole clause. So if the text is `abcde`, and the pattern is `(.*)e`, the `(.*)` wouldn't capture everything, only `abcd`. If you want specific characters, just change it to something like `[/\w\d]*/<and so on>` where that slash after the asterisk would be the last possible slash that would still satisfy the whole pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Don't need the `*` between the two expressions here, also move the first `/` into the brackets:

```
>>> regex = re.compile('([/a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)\.?$')
>>> regex.match('/foo/bar/baz').group(1)
'/foo/bar'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you may don't need regex.
You can simply use `split` function.

```
text = "/foo/bar/baz"
"/".join(text.split("/", 3)[:3])
```

output:

```
/foo/bar
```

`a.split("/", 3)` splits your string up to the third occurrence of `/`,  and then you can join the desidered elements.

As suggested by Niel, you can use a negative index to extract anything but the last part from  a url (or a path).

In this case the generic approach would be :

```
text = "/foo/bar/baz/boo/bye"
"/".join(text.split("/", -1)[:-1])
```

Output:

```
/foo/bar/baz/boo
```

Comment: You might want to make it more generic because if the URL changed to `"/foo/doo/bar/baz"` which is very likely for URLs, this will then fail due to its static indexing of `"3"`. Probably make `"-1"` would work too.

Comment: Thanks Niel, i edited my answer for  a generic approach.