# Regex Pattern repeat capturing group with special characters and spaces

Tags: java, regex

Am trying to capture repeated group, for the following string.

> ... and abc ( xyz(d.e),'f','g','h','i',xyz('p/q'),'r') = u...

and i do expect the output to be grouped in different matches in the below format

```
xyz(d.e)
'f'
'g'
'h'
'i'
xyz('p/q')
'r'
```

The closest solution i could find was this https://stackoverflow.com/a/65244969 . So i did try with

> abc\s*((?:([^,]+),?)

and got the output as

> xyz(d.e)

However when i do try with

> abc\s*((?:([^,]+),?)+

I get

> 'r') = u...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try `(?:\G(?!\A),|abc\s*\()\s*(\w+\('.*?'\)|'[^']*'|[^,']+)` and grab Group 1 values, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/SgSN5e/1).

Comment: Is your expectation correct? I think it should probably be `abc('p/q')` instead of `xyz('p/q')` correct?

Answer (score 0):

In your example strings you have either a part between single quotes or a part starting with word characters followed by parenthesis.

As your tried patterns start with abc, you might use:

```
(?:abc\s*\(\s*|\G(?!^),)('[^',]*'|\w+\([^()]*\))
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture grouop

  - `abc\s*\(\s*` Match `abc` a space followed by `(` between optional whitepace chars
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^),` Assert the position at the end of the previous match, but not at the start of the string to get repetitive matches. Following by matching a comma.
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `'[^',]*'` Match from `'...'` without matching `'` or a comma in between
  - `|` Or
  - `\w+\([^()]*\)` Match 1+ word chars followed by `(...)`
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ahxFjk/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/CCIojQ)

Example code getting the group 1 value:

```
String regex = "(?:abc\\s*\\(\\s*|\\G(?!^),)('[^',]*'|\\w+\\([^()]*\\))";
String string = "and abc ( xyz(d.e),'f','g','h','i',abc('p/q'),'r') = u";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    if (null != matcher.group(1)) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
}
```

Output

```
xyz(d.e)
'f'
'g'
'h'
'i'
abc('p/q')
'r'
```