# Regex search all matches without discarding previously matched items

Tags: regex, vba, multiple-matches

if I have a string
"2A3"
and I need to extract all combinations of
digit followed by letter
AND
letter followed by digit

so this should return
2A
and
A3

i tried
\d[A-Z]|[A-Z]\d
but it returns only 1 combination
How to fix this ?

Comment: This should be pretty straightforward. Google 'excel VBA combinations'.

Comment: This may answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37004214/7170711

Comment: Use this: `(?=(\d[A-Z]|[A-Z]\d))`