# How do I add conditions to search for specific substrings before or after intended string of search in regex?

Tags: python, regex

Problem: I have to find valid hex colours in a file, but not to include any selectors that potentially might conflict with it.

For example, in the below code,

```
#Cab
{
    background-color: #ABC;
    border: 2px dashed #fff;
}
```

`#ABC` and `#fff` are valid, but not `#cab` .

Question:
Is it possible to put condition for substring before and after the intended string of search.
Here, i need this `#[0-9a-fA-F]{3,3}|#[0-9a-fA-F]{6,6}` to be searched. But only if the substring immediately before it is `:[\w\s]*` and substring immediately after it is `\W`

Note 1: I figured that searching for `\W` after the string can be be done by adding `\b` in the original search.

Note 2: This was a problem in python, and I could trim it through python, but wondering if there is a way to do this through regex.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import re
string = """
#Cab
{
    background-color: #ABC;
    border: 2px dashed #fff;
    border:         2px dashed #ffe;
    border:         2px     #123;
    color:#ff00ff;
    color: #FfFdF8; background-color:#aef;
}
"""

pattern = re.compile(r':\s*[\w\s]*(#[0-9A-F]{3}|#[0-9A-F]{6});', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
match = re.findall(pattern, string)  # where 'string' is your input

print(match)
```

which produces

```
['#ABC', '#fff', '#ffe', '#123', '#ff00ff', '#FfFdF8', '#aef']
```

Comment: thank you both.. solves my question with usage of `()`. I modified pattern `:[\w\s\-,\(\)\#]*(#[0-9a-fA-F]{3}|#[0-9a-fA-F]{6})[\(\)\,\s\-]?[;|,]` to account for extreme cases for eg, colour gradient where multiple colours are separated by commas and inside a bracket. Still it failed in cases where 2 colours were there in a single group (one match per group). To find multiple matches in single group I used this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003623/how-to-capture-multiple-repeated-groups