# Is it possible to recursively capture a FINITE number of matches (all of the same format) using ECMA RegEx?

Tags: javascript, regex, recursion, capture-group

For instance, say we're looking at a query string, all-lowercase, all non-numeric, no special character (just `[a-z]` and `=`):

```
?some=querystring&ssembly=containing&n=indeterminate&mount=of&ll=potentially&ccordant=matches
```

Let us take as a given we know there will be three key-value pairs we wish to capture, and even that they are located at the beginning of said string:

- `some=querystring`
- `ssembly=containing`
- `n=indeterminate`

Now, intuitively, it seems like I *should* be able to use something like...

`^\?(&?[a-z=]+){3}.*$`

...or possibly...

`^\?(?:&?([a-z=]+)){3}.*$`

...but, of course, the only capture this yields is

`n=indeterminate`

**Is there a syntax that would allow me to capture all three groups (as independent, accessible values, natch) without having to resort to the following?**

`^\?([a-z=]+)&([a-z=]+)&([a-z=]+).*$`

I know there's no way to capture *n* instances (an arbitrarily-large set), but, given this is a *finite* number of captures I wish to obtain from my finite automata...

**I know full well there are any number of ways to accomplish this in Javascript, or any other language for that matter. I'm specifically trying to ascertain if I'm stuck with the WET expression above.**

Comment: Why not use a URL parser, like the one built in to browsers ([URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL))?

Comment: Do you have to use regex?  If you can using [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) might be easier.

Comment: Because I was looking for a contrived example to illustrate the point. I'm not literally attempting to parse a querystring. It could have just as easily been `fruit i like: bananas,strawberries,peaches,apples,oranges` and run with `^.*?: (([a-z]*?),){3}.*$`. The point is to ascertain if there's a regex syntax I'm unaware of, or if I'm SOL on this one. It's not a big deal to repeat thrice, but if I wish to capture the first 200 of something...

Comment: I would say just capture them all and then narrow down that result afterwards

Comment: In general you can have a regex capture just one of those patterns at a time, and loop over the matches until you have had enough of them. See `matchAll` method, which returns an iterator, or the old-fashioned `exec` method.

Comment: It's not clear what the word "recursion" has to do with anything here.

Comment: @Pointy The point is that I want to know if there's a way to make the expression LOOP BACK over the capture group until three, separate instances have been accumulated.

Comment: No, JS does not have support for recursive regexes. But what you want to match is not recursive. Recursive examples are nested parentheses. There is no nesting here. There seems to be a misunderstanding here about what "recursion" means in the context of regexes.

Comment: OK so a pattern with a `*` or `+`

Comment: The second of my examples are using nested parentheticals. I'm simply using `{3}` instead of `*` or `+` to dictate a finite number of recurses.

Comment: Recursion in regexes is about the **input strings** having a recursive pattern (nesting). I'm not speaking of the regex where you might have nested parentheses. There is no nesting in your input example. There are two questions here: does JS regex support recursion? How to match 3 occurrences of the same pattern without bloating a regex? Both are different questions and not related, since your input is not an example of a recursive pattern.

Comment: @trincot I see. Okay, so, if I change the word to "repetitive" or "reoccuring" do you know how to do it?

Comment: See my comment above. `matchAll` returns an iterator.

Comment: So not exclusively within the RegEx expression then? Yes, I can .match, or .matchAll, or .split, or any other number of JS means. Shoot, I can do it with .replace even easier. It's the RE I'm after.

Comment: Just apply the regex three times, with advancing positions?

Comment: @Bergi, do you know a way to accomplish this in the RegEx itself!? I know there's a sticky flag... I'm not sure how the syntax would flow though.

Comment: @NerdyDeeds To do it in regex, you have to repeat the expression so that you have multiple capture groups to capture the different parts - like the one you've shown but don't like.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to capture multiple repeated groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003623/how-to-capture-multiple-repeated-groups)

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer: If it is a solution you are looking for and not a way to bend over backwards, just use something like [`(?<=^[^:]+:.*)\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/EefXNf/2).

Comment: There are so many comment around here that I don't know if you answered it already, but can't you just capture all pairs? [`RegExp("([a-z]+=[a-z]+).*?", 'g');`](https://regex101.com/r/n4Nrfs/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would take a complex explanation to describe the nuance how the *FIRST* continuous
specific number of non-breaking segments are done in the various flavors of Regex Engines.

This JavaScript regex below does that task and is really the only way to do it in JS.
Note that this regex will fail for any number of continuous segments less than 3.
You can test it here https://regex101.com/r/3oWjwz/1

Other engines have different tools to work with to accomplish this task.
For example the Dot Net engine is by far the most comprehensive tool bed for doing these things (*Capture Colections*) [^?(?:&?([a-z=]+)(?![a-z=])){3}.*$](https://regex101.com/r/S7at3f/1)

```js
var input = '?some=querystring&ssembly=containing&n=indeterminate&mount=of&ll=potentially&ccordant=matches'

var regex = RegExp("(?<=^\\?(?=(?:&?[a-z=]+(?![a-z=])){3})(?:&?[a-z=]+){0,2}&?)[a-z=]+", 'g');

console.log( input.match(regex) );
```

A List of how this is applied to different Quantified Forms.

***Quantifier Unlimited   +***
https://regex101.com/r/bOGyJy/1

```
# Quantifier Unlimited +  
# (?<=^\?(?:&?[a-z=]+(?![a-z=]))*&?)[a-z=]+
# https://regex101.com/r/bOGyJy/1

(?<=
   ^ \? 
   (?:
      &? [a-z=]+ 
      (?! [a-z=] )
   )*
   &?
)
[a-z=]+
```

***Quantifier Exact  {3}***
https://regex101.com/r/3oWjwz/1

```
# Quantifier Exact {3}  
# (?<=^\?(?=(?:&?[a-z=]+(?![a-z=])){3})(?:&?[a-z=]+){0,2}&?)[a-z=]+
# https://regex101.com/r/3oWjwz/1

(?<=
   ^ \? 
   (?=
      (?:
         &? [a-z=]+ 
         (?! [a-z=] )
      ){3}                     # Exact range 3
   )
   (?: &? [a-z=]+ ){0,2}       # Zero to one less tham max range
   &?
)
[a-z=]+
```

***Quantifier Range   {2,4}***
https://regex101.com/r/D1NrLQ/1

```
# Quantifier Range {2,4}  
# (?<=^\?(?=(?:&?[a-z=]+(?![a-z=])){2,4})(?:&?[a-z=]+){0,3}&?)[a-z=]+
# https://regex101.com/r/D1NrLQ/1

(?<=
   ^ \? 
   (?=
      (?:
         &? [a-z=]+ 
         (?! [a-z=] )
      ){2}                     # 2 the minimum range
   )
   (?: &? [a-z=]+ ){0,3}       # Zero to one less than max range
   &?
)
[a-z=]+
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no recursion in EcmaScript regular expressions. Reference documentation is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Regular_expressions), you'll see there's no recursion operator. You can also check [regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html); it tells which engines support recursion: Perl 5.10, PCRE 4.0, Ruby 2.0, Delphi, PHP, and R.

Comment: Again: I know how to do this any number of ways in JS. I'm asking specifically _if it's possible_ to do in RegEx. The answer may well be, "No."

Comment: @NerdyDeeds um, this answer uses regex, and is just suggesting a change to your regex that (AFAICT) does what you want, so...wth?

Comment: I thought you wanted to do it in JS with a regexp.

Comment: I want to use the ECMA RE engine to accomplish the task. JS uses a different RegEx Engine than does, say, PHP, or Python.
@Jared Smith: I'm trying to see if there's a way to RECURSIVELY capture using ECMA RE. It's wholly possible it is NOT.

Comment: I don't know what the ECMA RE engine is. I assumed you were using ECMA as an abbreviation for EcmaScript, which is essentially the same as JavaScript.

Comment: You have the question tagged `javascript`.

Comment: PCRE has recursion. If ECMA is like JavaScript, it doesn't have recursion.

Comment: Because I'm trying to use the ECMA (Javascript) RE Engine. "PCRE has recursion. If ECMA is like JavaScript, it doesn't have recursion." THAT'S what I'm trying to verify. I don't THINK it can, but I'm hoping someone knows some voodoo I don't.

Comment: I don't know how to use the engine except from JavaScript.

Comment: You can read the RegExp docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Regular_expressions). You can easily see that it doesn't have a recursion operator.

Comment: @NerdyDeeds ah ok, **that** makes sense. But that's not what you said in the comment, which is why I was like, hrrm. No worries.

Comment: @Barmar That would be the docs that say, "Note: JavaScript regular expressions are in fact not regular, due to the existence of backreferences (regular expressions must have finite states). However, they are still a very useful feature." above the fold on the page you just sent me?

Comment: I thought you were looking for a way to get the result you wanted, not just an academic answer about recursion. I've rewritten the answer.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you very much. And, indeed, if nobody chimes in with a hackery-jiggery-pokery means of accomplishing this task, I'll mark your response as correct, as it will be the first one delivered with that answer. I've been told a LOT of things "aren't possible" programming until someone figures out a way to trick it into happening. Shoot, how may times have you heard one cannot parse HTML with RegEx? Earlier this year someone released a fully-working technique. I'm consulting the wisdom of the Stack before giving up.

Comment: It's not really true recursion I'm after, either. Not really. It's a finite number of iterations across the same capture rule. I don't care if it's using a recursive operator; I'm just trying to determine if anyone knows a good way to manage it.

Comment: @NerdyDeeds Can you show (in your question) how to make the same capturing group capture different parts of the string in the other languages you mention (PHP, Python) using their regex features (recursion and whatnot)?

Comment: I don't think that what you want can be done with recursion at all. Recursive regular expressions are for parsing nested structures, like parenthesized expressions. Also, I don't think there's a way to stop after 3 iterations -- you recurse until there's no match for the nested pattern.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has no concept of recursion in its regex syntax, but the example you have given is not about recursion, but adjacent repetition of the same pattern.

In that case I would suggest using a regex that just matches one occurrence of that pattern, but with the `g` flag, and use it with `matchAll`. This returns an iterator, and so you just consume the part that you need.

If it is guaranteed that you will have three matches, you can do:

```js
const input = "?some=querystring&assembly=containing&n=indeterminate&mount=of&ll=potentially&ccordant=matches";
const [[a],[b],[c]] = input.matchAll(/\w+=\w+/g);
console.log(a, b, c);
```

This is just an example that is targeting your example. As `matchAll` returns an iterator, you can use the power of JS to work with iterators (like a `for` loop, destructuring assignment, spread syntax, ...etc).

#### Alternative: dynamically built regex

The repetitive nature of the regex you are troubled about can be taken over by the `repeat()` method:

```js
const input = "?some=querystring&assembly=containing&n=indeterminate&mount=of&ll=potentially&ccordant=matches";
const regex = RegExp("([a-z]+=[a-z]+)&?".repeat(3));
const [, ...matches] = input.match(regex);
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: Again: we established in the comments above both the semantics surrounding recursion, and established this is a contrived example. And, to reiterate: I _know_ how to do so in JS. This is about using the ECMA RegEx ENGINE to accomplish the task, if, indeed, it's even possible to DO. Taking your example, above. Say I want to capture the first 75 instances. Do you destructure 75 variables? (This is a rhetorical question).

Comment: Why would you want 75 variables? Obviously you'd want an array in that case, and so an array will need to be populated.

Comment: I don't _want_ THREE variables. I want to know if there is a syntax that will allow the same, single regular expression to form three capture groups without my needing to write out all three!

Comment: So then dynamically write the regex, using `.repeat(n)` and passing it to the RegExp constructor?

Comment: Okay, let's try it like this: Go to https://regex101.com/r/TejRda/1. That includes the example above. Write an expression into the input field at the top of the page that will capture three key-value pairs (I don't even care which ones) without having to write out the same `(key=value&?)` expression thrice, a la `(key=value&?)(key=value&?)(key=value&?)`.

Comment: That's not possible. You need as many capture groups as you want to... capture.

Comment: Which is 100% of the question I asked. Is. It. Possible? If the answer is "no", so be it. I'll move on with my life. I'm asking to see if there's a trick I'm unaware of.

Comment: Well, I guess with all the questions for clarification and definition of terms ("recursion"), you've seen all sides of the subject in the comments. A question may be clear to you from the start, but bare with the others who need to  get into your head to really understand what you are on about.