# Regex substitution for variable number of capturing groups | Mass XML doc editing in Visual Studio

Tags: regex, visual-studio, xml-documentation

This is a many-in-one question.

I want to inject newlines into the xml documentation of my C# project.
Going from

```
/// <summary>
/// Event for lazy async var reading. 
/// Contains all vars that partecipated to a certain poll,  
/// indepentently of the fact it succeded or the value changed </summary>
```

to

```
/// <summary>
/// <br>Event for lazy async var reading. </br>
/// <br>Contains all vars that partecipated to a certain poll,</br>  
/// <br>indepentently of the fact it succeded or the value changed </br></summary>
```

My first approach was running a Regex find & replace, and i managed to correctly select the comments accounting for different indentations and such.

When it comes to capturing groups tho, i'm not finding a way to reference the lines making up the body.
Both the line's capturing group and inner capturing groups seem to go missing.

My regex:

```
(?x:
    (?(DEFINE)
        (?'line'\/\/\/\s*([^\n]+)\n*)
    )
    (?'head'<summary>(?:\s*\n | \s*[^\n]+\n*))  #select summary tag and skip the first line.
    (?P>line)+                                  #select each line, capturing both the line and a subset of its content
    (?'foot'(?:\/\/\/\s*)*<\/summary>)          #select summary closure and the empty comment-lines preceding it
)
```

this expression produces

```
{0}:  full match  
{1 (named head)}:   \<summary\>...  
{4}:  last matched (?P>line)  
{5 (named foot)}:   ...\</summary\>
```

where did capturing groups {2} and {3} go?
where did `(?'line'..)`'s inner capturing group go?
Is there an Visual studio extension that's up to the task instead?

Even if the regex worked, i don't know how to reference all the in-between groups, as their number is variable.
My plan is referencing all numbered group explicitly up to some number, and have the others named to avoid selection. Is there a better alternative?

p.s. if there is a way to post regex "code" formatted in a color-coded pretty way, i didn't find it. Any pointers are welcome.

p.p.s. EDIT: [related questions i was apparently unable to find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003623/how-to-capture-multiple-repeated-groups?rq=2) stated that "it's not feasable by regex alone, just through functions in actual languages"

Comment: Using `(?P>line)+` you are repeating the expression defined in the capture group line, but that by itself is not in a capture group. You might surround it by another capture group `lines` https://regex101.com/r/TgW6Zd/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird that's because what i want to capture is a group inside each line, not the sum of all the lines. i want to end up with a collection of N captured line-parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can clearly be done by regex alone.
Visual Studio does not have a usable regex engine.
This can however be done in C# using Capture Collections.

You can bite the bullet and use the Pcre engine too.
Here is an idea for you.

```
(?m)(?:^///\h*<summary>\h*(?:\s*^///\h*)*\K(?'line'(?:(?!</?summary\s*>)\S)+(?:\h*(?:(?!</?summary\s*>)\S)+)*)|\G(?:\s*^///\h*)*\K(?&line))
```

Substitute `<br>$0</br>`

https://regex101.com/r/bdbVMw/1

Rx layout:

```
(?m)
(?:
   ^ /// \h* <summary> \h* 
   (?: \s* ^ /// \h* )*
   \K        
   (?'line'                      # (1 start)
      (?: (?! </?summary \s* > ) \S )+
      (?: \h* (?: (?! </?summary \s* > ) \S )+ )*
   )                             # (1 end)
   
 | \G 
   (?: \s* ^ /// \h* )*
   \K (?&line) 
)
```

Comment: I've yet to decipher the inner workings of this regex (and i plan to! ty). That said how do i run RegExps on a .NET source? As you said Visual Studio lacks built in support.. Have you got any pointers on Extensions or cmd line tools that may be up for the task?

Comment: @AndreaBardelli Don't get confused by what you're parsing the _Target_ and what that text is, as you say _`.NET source`_ which for the most part is irrelevant. I purposely did not explain the Pcre regex above. Did not want to confuse you. It is a line by line matching regex. It is constrained to be relevant to the outcome intended.  This can be run _as is_ on NP++. Using .NET regex engine on one of MS languages, Capture Collection can be used in a single match to do all that you need. It is a 5 line C# program. Do you want that ? No such thing as tools to do this.

Comment: notepad++/ctrl-f/find in files tab: finally a proper way of running regexps on my projects :D.    
About your expression: If i got it right, the general idea is having whole matches instead of a variable number of captured groups. To accomplish this we use lookahead and lookbehinds stating that a line is "something that is preceded by <summary> and 0 or more lines, and is followed by 0 or more lines and a </summary> tag".

Comment: @AndreaBardelli The insinuation is that _<summary>_ is a single, non-nested, and has a closing tag. Therefore each non-space character must not start a summary tag, either open or closed. It skips ahead this way. However, it could be written to added segment look ahead, that strictly ensures there exists a closing tag down stream that is not nested and malformed, if that is a concern. The C# regex is different in that it matches the entire valid form while capturing a variable number of groups. All in a single match.