Making sense of the regex in grep command
When executing the following command in a bash shell:
grep '^\(.\)*\1$' exp.txt

I expect it to match any line that:

begins and ends with the same latter.

but in reality it matches the following lines:
Ritchie at Bell
Laboratories in the late 1960s. Onee
- first of all my name is ...
TTTTTTTTTTTTTT

I understand why it selected TTTTTTTTTTTTTT since it begins and ends with the same character, but I don't know why it selected the rest.
I know that adding a dot before the asterisk '^\(.\).*\1$' will do what I desire (selecting lines that begin and end with the same character), but I still would like to know why '^\(.\)*\1$' doesn't work as expected.
The full file (exp.txt) is:
The Unix operating system was pioneered
by
Ken
Thompson and Dennis
Ritchie at Bell
Laboratories in the late 1960s. Onee
of the primary
goals in the design of the Unix system was to create an environment that
promoted efficient program
development.
[my name]
.Hi man
HHi man
my mamamamamama my
mohammad
space      spacesm
first char is same as last f
- first of all my name is ...
T
TT
TTTT
TTTTT
TTTTTT
TTTTTTT
TTTTTTTTTTTTTT


This question has answer here: How to capture multiple repeated groups?. Specifically, https://stackoverflow.com/a/37004214 states: repeated capture group retains content only from the last iteration. You can also consider this pic - group 1 matches 5 times, stores only "5" (that is the last iteration).

A  repeated capturing  group, such  as (.)*,  puts in  the
memory what was captured last. That's where the confusion is
coming from.
As your group is a  wildcard ((.)), it will match anything
and whatever was  matched last will remain  in \1. Simpler
example (again in the more common (enhanced) regex style):
/(.)*/
aabbcc     # matches everything, but \1 contains `c`

This might be  strange at first glance, but  makes sense: it
repeats  a  wildcard  of  a single  character.  So,  matches
everything.  Finally, whatever  was  last  captures is  what
remains in capture group memory.
To  capture  a  repeated  occurrence, one  needs  to  repeat
explicitly:
/(.)\1*/
aabbcc     # matches `aa` and \1 contains `a`

In the example above, (.)  matches the first character and
then it is repeated.
Back to  your original expression (here  expressed in grep's
basic notation):
^\(.\)*\1$

Beginning  tied  to the  start  (^),  it matches  anything
(\(.\)), as  many times as  possible (*), and  then asks
for a repeat of the last matched character at the end ($).
In plain English:

Match any line that ends with a repeated character.

Achieving  what you  originally wanted  (lines starting  and
ending with the  same character) is possible  with the regex
you already mentioned in your question:
grep '^\(.\).*\1$' filename


In POSIX, backreferences are not supported in EREs, only in BREs, so in (.)\1* if it's a BRE then the ( and ) are literal and \1 is not populated while in an ERE the ( and ) do enclose a subexpression but then \1 is an escaped "ordinary character" and so is undefined behavior (which some versions of some tools can take advantage of to define it to mean a backreference, but that's not portable to other versions of the same tool). grep '^\(.\).*\1$' IS defined behavior and will do what the OP wants but in the regexps above it, where you say ... and \1 contains ... YMMV.
