# Searching for strings starting with \n\n in Swift

Tags: ios, regex, swift

Hey I have a requirement to increase the spacing in my UILables for double spaced line breaks. I want to search my string and find all the strings starting with `\n\n`. For example "`Hello world\nI am on the next line\n\nNow I'm on the next line and it's spaced more than before\nNow I'm back to normal spacing"`. I'm having trouble trying to figure out the regex for this. I am trying:

```
let regExRule = "^\n\n*"
```

and passing it into this function:

```
func matchesForRegexInText(regex: String, text: String) -> [String] {

        do {
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex, options: [])
            let nsString = text as NSString
            let results = regex.matchesInString(text,
                                                options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, nsString.length))
            return results.map { nsString.substringWithRange($0.range)}
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return []
        }
    }
```

However I am getting an empty array. Not really sure how to construct the regex pattern for this. Any pointers would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You want string between `\n` or two `\n\n` because two`\n\n` occur only once.

Comment: Strictly spoken in your sample string there is no string *enclosed* in two linefeed characters. By the way: Declaring the parameters as implicit unwrapped optionals is nonsense in this case.

Comment: @vadian you're right. question edited.

Comment: @vadian: With respect to the IUOs: I might be to blame for that. The function (as originally posted in this question) is what I answered here http://stackoverflow.com/a/27880748/1187415, where I copied the IUOs from the question without thinking about it. Or maybe there was a reason in Swift 1.2, I don't remember. Anyway, I have fixed that now.

Answer (score 2):

The primary issue I see is the regex pattern should include a capture group to select the multiple strings needed.

```
func matchesForRegexInText(regex : String, text: String) -> [String] {
    var captured = [String]()
    let exp = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex, options: [])
    let matches = exp.matchesInString(text, options:[], range: NSMakeRange(0, text.characters.count))

    for match in matches {
        let c = (text as NSString).substringWithRange(match.rangeAtIndex(1))
        captured.append(c)
    }

    return captured
}

let re = "\\n\\n([\\w\\\\s,']+)"; // selection with (...)

// ["Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie"]
let strResults = matchesForRegexInText(re, text: "\n\nAlpha\n\nBravo\n\nCharlie\n\n")
```

Comment: I updated my example. I had misread your question thinking you were using literal `\n` characters instead of new lines. I think the update will help.