# Update a Range in Swift 3

Tags: swift, string, range, swift3

I'm trying to search a `String` for `regex` using the following snippet (it's in an extension for `String`):

```
var range = self.startIndex..<self.endIndex

while range.lowerBound < range.upperBound {
    if let match = self.range(of: regex, options: .regularExpression, range: range, locale: nil) {

        print(match)
        range = ????? <============  this line, how do I update the range?
    }
}
```

It will correctly find the first occurance, but then I don't know how to change the range to the position of the match to search the remainder of the string.

Comment: What are you trying to do inside that `while` loop? Seems like an infinite loop even if you can update the range. And I think using `NSRegularExpression` is a lot cleaner

Comment: Point well taken, any suggestions how to make this loop work?  I will look at `NSRegularExpression` as well.

Comment: @MartinR: I ended up using `NSRegularExpression`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`lowerBound` and `upperBound` are immutable properties of the range,
so you have to create a new range, starting at `match.upperBound`.

Also the loop should terminate if no match is found. 
That can be achieved by moving the binding
`let match = ...` into the where condition.

```
var range = self.startIndex..<self.endIndex
while range.lowerBound < range.upperBound,
    let match = self.range(of: regex, options: .regularExpression, range: range) {
        print(match) // the matching range
        print(self.substring(with: match)) // the matched string

        range = match.upperBound..<self.endIndex
}
```

This can still lead to an infinite loop if an empty string matches
the pattern (e.g. for `regex = "^")`. This can be solved, but
as an alternative, use `NSRegularExpression` to get a list of all
matches (see for example [Swift extract regex matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880650/swift-extract-regex-matches/27880748#27880748)).