# Use regex to match emojis as well as text in string

Tags: ios, regex, swift

I am trying to find the range of specific substrings of a string. Each substring begins with a hashtag and can have any character it likes within it (including emojis). Duplicate hashtags should be detected at distinct ranges. A kind user from here suggested this code:

```
var str = "The range of #hashtag should be different to this #hashtag"
let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(#[A-Za-z0-9]*)", options: [])
let matches = regex.matchesInString(str, options:[], range:NSMakeRange(0, str.characters.count))
for match in matches {
    print("match = \(match.range)")
}
```

However, this code does not work for emojis. What would be the regex expression to include emojis? Is there a way to detect a `#`, followed by any character up until a space/line break?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Similarly as in [Swift extract regex matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880650/swift-extract-regex-matches/27880748#27880748),
you have to pass an `NSRange` to the match functions, and the
returned ranges are `NSRange`s as well. This can be achieved
by converting the given text to an `NSString`.

The `#\S+` pattern matches a `#` followed by one or more
non-whitespace characters.

```
let text = "The range of #hashtag should  be  different to this #hashtag"

let nsText = text as NSString
let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "#\\S+", options: [])
for match in regex.matchesInString(text, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: nsText.length)) {
    print(match.range)
    print(nsText.substringWithRange(match.range))
}
```

Output:

```
(15,10)
#hashtag
(62,10)
#hashtag
```

You can also convert between `NSRange` and `Range<String.Index>`
using the methods from [NSRange to Range<String.Index>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25138339/nsrange-to-rangestring-index/30404532#30404532).

*Remark:* As @WiktorStribiżew correctly noticed, the above pattern
will include trailing punctuation (commas, periods, etc). If 
that is not desired then

```
let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "#[^[:punct:][:space:]]+", options: [])
```

would be an alternative.

Comment: Note that `#\\S+` will also match punctuation at the end of the hashtag.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: You are right, but the question was about how *"to detect a #, followed by any character up until a space/line break"*, and OP stated that hashtags can contain *arbitrary* characters.

Comment: Actually it might be a good idea just to have it as a hashtag followed by only  letters, numbers, and emojis ... For bonus points could you give the regex that would be for that?

Comment: @Tometoyou: If you search for "regex emojis" then you should find some approaches, I do not have an immediate solution, also the set of Emoji characters grows with each Unicode release. – I have updated the answer with a simpler solution which excludes punctuation.

Comment: Ok thanks! One more thing, I've just noticed that the range for your answer should be (14, 9) and (56,  9). Is there anyway to make it count emojis as 1 character?

Comment: @Tometoyou: Emojis count as two characters in an `NSString` and that is what `NSRange` refers to. You can convert the NSRange back to a Swift `String` range using the `rangeFromNSRange` method at http://stackoverflow.com/a/30404532/1187415 that I linked to.

Comment: RegEx fails when multiple #tags together.
the text `Some text #tagg#gshd some more text`
matches only 1 tag `#tagg#gshd`, @MartinR is there a workaround to avoid this, thanks

Comment: @Aamir: Did you try the other pattern `"#[^[:punct:][:space:]]+"` ?

Comment: Oh just noticed, will try in an hour and let you know, thanks

Comment: @MartinR The other pattern works perfectly, thanks for pointing out