# what's wrong with this function to extract hashtags from string in Swift?

Tags: swift, nsstring

I have this extension:

```
extension String {
    public func seperateHashtags(char : String) -> [String]{
        var word : String = ""
        var words : [String] = [String]()
        for chararacter in self.characters {
            if String(chararacter) == char && word != "" {
                words.append(word)
                word = char
            }else {
                word += String(chararacter)
            }
        }
        words.append(word)
        return words
    }
}
```

and I want to get an array of hashtags from any given text. 
I have a `UITextView` that contains the text:

```
write anything here... #one #two three #four
```

and I expect to have an output:

```
["one", "two", "four"]
```

but when I do this:

```
print(myTextView.text.seperateHashtags("#"))
```

I'm getting:

```
["write anything here... ", "#one ", "#two three ", "#four"]
```

how can I fix that?

Comment: Use the debugger. Single-step through your code. Inspect variables. Where does the function not do what you expect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use regex and get all the hashtag like this way:

```
var hashtags = [String]()
var str = "#one #two three #four"
let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(#[A-Za-z0-9]*)", options: [])
let matches = regex.matchesInString(str, options:[], range:NSMakeRange(0, str.characters.count))
for match in matches {
    print("match = \(match.range)")
    hashtags.append(NSString(string: str).substringWithRange(NSRange(location:match.range.location + 1, length:match.range.length - 1)))
}
```

**Output:**

```
["one", "two", "four"]
```

Comment: hm I just pasted it to my code and this line `let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(#[A-Za-z0-9]*)", options: [])` throws me an error that says: `Errors thrown from here are not handled`... What might be wrong here?

Comment: You need to add that inside `do catch` block.

Comment: Welcome mate :)

Comment: Try this with `var str = " #one #two three #four"` :)

Comment: @user3766930 if you want to use emoji also with hashtag then this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39701316/use-regex-to-match-emojis-as-well-as-text-in-string

Comment: Awesome, I suppose this pattern find word boundaries, is it?, is it possible you to explain the pattern, thanks

Comment: @Aamir This pattern will find a word that start with # and word having character from a-z A-Z and 0-9

Answer (score 0):

```
write anything here...
```

Shouldn't you put this as a placeholder for the UITextField?

Comment: yes, but besides that I can write any text there and I'm still getting it recognized as a hashtag...