# How to check given character lies between A to Z in Swift 3.0?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

My problem is unary operator is not in  Swift 3.0  Below is my snippet.

```
func  checkCharacter(x: Character)  {
   if x >= "a" || x <="z"{
   }
}
```

How to check that given character lies between a to z in swift 3.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like this.

```
func checkCharacter(x: Character) {

    if x >= "a" && x <= "z" {
        print("Inside character range")
    }
    else {
        print("Not inside character range")
    }
}

checkCharacter(x: "c")
```

Comment: I think the problem is with your `||`/ `or` operator it should be and instead of or.

Comment: >= operator in not allowed in swift3.0

Comment: try to execute your code in Xcode 8. You will get error regarding unary operator.

Comment: yup its working but intially I got error.Now  I have replaced && operator with || and its working fine.

Comment: @akshay You are doing wrong if you want the perfect result then it must be && not ||.

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly recommend using a regex like this

```
    let testStr = "a"
    let matches = self.matchesForRegexInText(regex: "^[a-zA-Z]+$", text: testStr)

    if matches.count > 0 {
        //string contains only a-z or A-Z
    }

func matchesForRegexInText(regex: String, text: String) -> [String] {

    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex, options: [])
        let nsString = text as NSString
        let results = regex.matches(in: text,
                                            options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, nsString.length))
        return results.map { nsString.substring(with: $0.range)}
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return []
    }
}
```

edit: I stole the code without mentioning it: [Swift extract regex matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880650/swift-extract-regex-matches/27880748#27880748)

Comment: if I dont wan't to use regex .Is there any other solution to solve my problem.

Comment: why are you not wanting a regex?