# How to use regular expressions in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, regex, swift3, nsregularexpression

I wanted to follow [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/86205/nsregularexpression-swift-tutorial) to learn about `NSRegularExpression` in `Swift`, but it has not been updated to `Swift 3`. When I open the playground with the examples they provide, I get several errors being one of them the call:

```
let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .allZeros, error: nil)
```

I've seen that now that initializer throws an exception so I changed the call, but that `.allZeros` does not seem to exist anymore. I don't find any tutorial or example with an equivalent of that in `Swift 3`, could somebody tell me what option should now replace such `.allZeros` option?

Comment: This may helps http://stackoverflow.com/q/27880650/6521116

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe `.allZeros` was to be used when no other options applied.

So with Swift 3, you can pass an empty list of options or leave out the `options` parameter since it defaults to no options:

```
do {
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])
} catch {
}
```

or

```
do {
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern)
} catch {
}
```

Note that in Swift 3 you don't use the `error` parameter any more. It now `throws`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `[]`:

```
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])
```

which is also the default value, so you can omit this argument:

```
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern)
```

The easiest way to find this out is to command+click jump to the methods definition:

```
public init(pattern: String, options: NSRegularExpression.Options = []) throws
```