# How to extract words (english) and names from a string in Swift 3.0?

Tags: ios, swift, string

I'm using an image processing API that reads text on the image, and from the string data I get back, I need to extract words in the English language or dictionary and common first and last names.  In other words I'm getting the text I need within the string but also some garbage in the results that I need to filter out (non-words).  What's the best approach here?  I've looked into `NSLinguisticTagger` but it's not 100% on point with what I'm doing, any other suggestions?

Would REGEX help me here?  I can't figure out how to form the syntax for a pattern that will match only words?

Below are 2 examples of sample string's I'm trying to pull words/names from:

(1) "PUMPER im CasSICI 1111 Cassu with Andrew Webster PUMPE im CasSICI 1111 Cassu with Andrew Webster"
// I need to extract:  "Pumper With Andrew Webster"

(2) "SHARON M DRAPER000k in the powerful Hazelwood High trilogyFORGEDBY FIRESWINNER SHARON M DRAPER 000k in the powerful Hazelwood High trilogy FORGED BY FIRE S WINNER" 
// I need to extract "Sharon Hazelwood High Draper in the powerful trilogy forced by fire winner"

Comment: I don't know how complex your problem is exactly, but you might need to look into stuff like NLP ( Natural Language Processing ), especially NER ( Name Entity Recognition ).

Comment: @GraySabo, I am not understand this line:`I need to extract words in English and names out of a string` what's mean of this?

Comment: Do you have a list of words/names you'd like to extract or are you looking for a pattern? If you're looking for a pattern, then could to use something like `Regex`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27880748/4475605 I threw a quick demo together https://github.com/AdrianBinDC/RegexDemo. If you're searching for specific strings, that's pretty easy.

Comment: Thanks guys, what I mean is I need to identify whether letters in a string form a word in the english dictionary (or slag etc.) or a common first or last name.

Comment: Re: common names, here's a list that might be helpful for checking your string against. https://github.com/fivethirtyeight/data/tree/master/most-common-name. Backing up a step, what OCR framework are you using? Will the font being OCR'd be the same every time? If so, you might be able to train your OCR w/ the font so you've got less of a hot OCR mess to deal with, which reduces the work you've got to do w/ pulling out data from the strings.

Comment: @Adrian thanks for the name list...using Google Cloud Vision, I thought maybe Google would have a method in the API to only give back words in english but I haven't found anything in the docs yet.

Comment: I've got an idea I think will get you most of the way there. Let me tinker around and I'll chuck something on Github when I'm done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've cobbled this class together, which is a mixture of real and pseudocode. I would create a singleton class for first names and last names. See comments in code for details. This isn't the whole thing, but it should solve most of your problem.

**Update**
Tweaked the `cleanUpString` method with a switch statement.

**Update 2**
Added this to take care of whatever `UITextChecker` doesn't...

```
return UIReferenceLibraryViewController.dictionaryHasDefinition(forTerm: self)
```

Wherever you're getting your OCR text from, you'd use it like this:

```
let stringParser = StringParser()
let cleanedUpText = stringParser.cleanUpString(yourOCRText)
```

Here's the class:

```
import UIKit // need this so UITextChecker will work
import Foundation

class StringParser: NSObject {

    // TODO: You'll need to create a singleton class for your first and last names
    // https://krakendev.io/blog/the-right-way-to-write-a-singleton

    func cleanUpString(_ inputString: String) -> String {

        // chuck stuff separated by a space into an array as an invdividual string
        let inputStringArray = inputString.characters.split(separator: " ").map(String.init)

        var outputArray = [String]()

        for word in inputStringArray {
            // Switch to check if word satisfies any of the desired conditions...if so, chuck in outputArray

            switch word {
            case _ where word.isRealWord():
                outputArray.append(word)
                break
            case _ where word.isFirstName():
                outputArray.append(word.capitalized)
                break
            case _ where word.isLastName():
                outputArray.append(word.capitalized)
                break
            default:
                break
            }
        }

        // reassemble the cleaned up words into an output array and return it as a single string
        return outputArray.joined(separator: " ")
    }
}

extension String {

    func isFirstName() -> Bool {
        let firstNameArray = ["Andrew", "Sharon"] // FIXME: this should be your singleton

        return firstNameArray.contains(self.capitalized)
    }

    func isLastName() -> Bool {
        let lastNameArray = ["Webster", "Hazelwood"] // FIXME: this should be your singleton

        return lastNameArray.contains(self.capitalized)
    }

    func isRealWord() -> Bool {
        // adapted from https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-check-a-string-is-spelled-correctly-using-uitextchecker
        let checker = UITextChecker()
        let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: self.utf16.count)
        let misspelledRange = checker.rangeOfMisspelledWord(in: self, range: range, startingAt: 0, wrap: false, language: "en")

        if misspelledRange.location == NSNotFound {
            // cleans up what UITextChecker misses
            return UIReferenceLibraryViewController.dictionaryHasDefinition(forTerm: self) // returns yes if there's a definition for it
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: This will work on a physical device, but the compiler will say there's no dictionary if you run it in simulator.

Comment: Thanks @Adrian! I really appreciate you taking the time.  I'm testing on a playground, should it work?  Doesn't seem like the dictionary is working as it's not returning true on english words?

Comment: @GarySabo I could only get 'UIReferenceLibraryViewController' to work on a physical device

Comment: Thanks @Adrian, finally had a chance to try on device and it works pretty well!  I'd like to get something eventually I could test on the simulator but this is a great solution.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Cool! This was one of those rare occasions where the OP was trying to do something that's close to something I was working on. If you figure out how to get `UIReferenceLibraryViewController`'s dictionary in simulator, feel free to update the answer and I'll do the same.