# Match a string against multiple regex patterns using Swift 3

Tags: regex, swift

Is there any way using swift 3 we can match a string with Multiple regular expression patterns. In Java, we usually pass them as below

```
[a-zA-Z]{3}|^[^\\d].*|([\\w&&[^b]])*
```

Is there any similar way we can do it using Swift.

Comment: There's not Regex in Swift itself (yet). You should use Foundation's [NSRegularExpression](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsregularexpression).

Comment: Are you asking if `|` is supported by  NSRegularExpression? Yes, it is.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I didn't try that..I don't know where I am going wrong. Do we have any func() which actually matches multiple NSRegularExpression

Comment: The `[\\w&&[^b]]` is most probably the culprit. In ICU, it is set as `[\\w--b]` (or `[\\w--[b]]`). As for multiple matches, no, you need to implement it. There are such questions on SO. See [Swift extract regex matches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880650/swift-extract-regex-matches).