# Get string range of string with variable parameters in swift 3

Tags: swift, string, swift3, textview

I'm currently making a text editor that reacts to "commands" with a (maybe not professional but) easy and fast if-Statement like the following

```
    if let quitRange = textView.string!.range(of: "/quit") {
     textField.string!.replaceSubrange(quitRange, with: "")
        NSApplication.shared().terminate(self)
    }
```

Now I'm wondering how I can get the range of the string with parameters. Something like

```
 "/encrypt[offSet:21]"
```

where my offSet Int is completely variable

Comment: Check out this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880650/swift-extract-regex-matches)

Comment: Looks good, I'll try it later, thank you very much :)