# Make sure regex matches the entire string with Swift regex

Tags: regex, swift

How to check whether a WHOLE string can be matches to regex? In Java is method `String.matches(regex)`

Comment: Do you only need a boolean as a result?

Comment: Yes, I only need a Bool result

Comment: Well, I doubt there is a specific *method* for it, can't you use `^` and `$` anchors with your pattern? I mean, do you define the pattern or is it user-defined?

Comment: I have defined a pattern and I check whether text introduced by user in TextField matches to a pattern

Comment: Ok, you need to just use `^` and `$` to define the start and end positions. There is `.anchored` option, but it works as `/A` in PHP, only anchors at the start of the string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use anchors, `^` (start of string anchor) and `$` (end of string anchor), with [`range(of:options:range:locale:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1642786-range), passing the `.regularExpression` option:

```
import Foundation

let phoneNumber = "123-456-789"
let result = phoneNumber.range(of: "^\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{3}$", options: .regularExpression) != nil
print(result)
```

Or, you may pass an array of options, `[.regularExpression, .anchored]`, where [`.anchored`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsregularexpression.matchingoptions/1410858-anchored) will anchor the pattern at the start of the string only, and you will be able to omit `^`, but still, `$` will be required to anchor at the string end:

```
let result = phoneNumber.range(of: "\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{3}$", options: [.regularExpression, .anchored]) != nil
```

See the [online Swift demo](http://rextester.com/CEHE88870)

Also, using `NSPredicate` with [`MATCHES`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-215868) is an alternative here:

> The left hand expression equals the right hand expression using a regex-style comparison according to ICU v3 (for more details see the ICU User Guide for [Regular Expressions](http://icu.sourceforge.net/userguide/regexp.html)).

**`MATCHES` actually anchors the regex match both at the start and end of the string** (*note this might not work in all Swift 3 builds*):

```
let pattern = "\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{3}"
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "self MATCHES [c] %@", pattern)
let result = predicate.evaluate(with: "123-456-789")
```

Answer (score 7):

What you are looking for is [`range(of:options:range:locale:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1642786-range) then you can then compare the result of range(of:option:) with whole range of comparing string..

**Example:**

```
let phoneNumber = "(999) 555-1111"
let wholeRange = phoneNumber.startIndex..<phoneNumber.endIndex
if let match = phoneNumber.range(of: "\\(?\\d{3}\\)?\\s\\d{3}-\\d{4}", options: .regularExpression), wholeRange == match {
    print("Valid number")
}
else {
    print("Invalid number")
}
//Valid number
```

**Edit:** You can also use `NSPredicate` and compare your string with [`evaluate(with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nspredicate/1417924-evaluate) method of its.

```
let pattern = "^\\(?\\d{3}\\)?\\s\\d{3}-\\d{4}$"
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "self MATCHES [c] %@", pattern)
if predicate.evaluate(with: "(888) 555-1111") {
    print("Valid")
}
else {
    print("Invalid")
}
```

Comment: I think `"\\(?\\d{3}\\)?\\s\\d{3}-\\d{4}"` will also allow partial matches. Add `^` and `$` anchors on both sides of the pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Edited answer

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that, too. I think there is still another way, but can't find a way to make NSPredicate work in Swift 3. It is really misfortunate that `.anchored` only anchors at the string start.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for remind me about `NSPredicate`, edited answer with that also

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It is compiling successfully on my Mac, Xcode 8.1

Comment: If you have an idea how to make it work everywhere, it would be the best approach.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Have you tried once running on Xcode because it looks like this bug with linux check this one https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-957

Comment: No, it is not [the only issue](http://rextester.com/ZCLMM88063). Mabe the NSPredicate was not ready  in Swift 3.0.2.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That may possible.

Answer (score 0):

[Swift extract regex matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880650/swift-extract-regex-matches)

with little bit of edit

```
import Foundation

func matches(for regex: String, in text: String) -> Bool {
    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex)
        let nsString = text as NSString
        let results = regex.matches(in: text, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: nsString.length))
        return !results.isEmpty
    } catch let error {
        print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return false
    }
}
```

Example usage from link above:

```
let string = "19320"
let matched = matches(for: "^[1-9]\\d*$", in: string)
print(matched) // will match

let string = "a19320"
let matched = matches(for: "^[1-9]\\d*$", in: string)
print(matched) // will not match
```