# NSRegularExpression to extract subset of text in Swift 3

Tags: regex, swift3, nsregularexpression

I am trying to use NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex) to extract 10.32.15.235 in a string: \"IPAddress\":\"10.32.15.235\",\"WAN\" using Swift 3.

However, I'm getting an error using this function from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880650/swift-extract-regex-matches)

```
func matches(for regex: String, in text: String) -> [String] {

    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex)
        let nsString = text as NSString
        let results = regex.matches(in: text, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: nsString.length))
        return results.map { nsString.substring(with: $0.range)}
    } catch let error {
        print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return []
    }
}
```

With this call:

```
        let pattern = "IPAddress\\\":\\\"(.+?)\\"
        let IPAddressString = self.matches(for: pattern, in: stringData!)
        print(IPAddressString)
```

However, the error part of the function is called with this error:

> invalid regex: The value “IPAddress\":\"(.+?)\” is invalid.

Can you help me modify the regex expression for Swift 3?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like it's missing an escaped double-quote at the end. Try with adding `\"` at the end of your pattern.

Comment: Use `let pattern = "(?<=IPAddress\":\")[^\"]+"`

Comment: Does it work as you want?

Answer (score 0):

Note that in case you have a valid JSON, you may use a JSON parser with Swift.

TO fix your current regex approach, you may use

```
let pattern = "(?<=IPAddress\":\")[^\"]+"
```

**Pattern details**

- `(?<=IPAddress\":\")` - a positive lookahead that matches a position in the string right after `IPAddress":"` substring
- `[^\"]+` - a negated character class matching 1 or more chars other than `"`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9zqgPa/1).