# Hashtags regex limit number of characters

Tags: ios, regex

I'm currently trying to limit the number of characters for matching hashtags.
I would like to match hashtags only if they have less than 25 characters.

This what I have (without the limit):

```
regex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"(#+[\\S\\_]+)?" options:0 error:&error];
```

I tried something like that, but without success:

```
regex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"(#+[\\S\\_]{0,10})?" options:0 error:&error];
```

If I launch the code like that, hashtags are matching but they are cut.

[image]

I would like to don't match at all if the hashtag is more than 25 characters; I tried to add `$` after `{0,10}` but it's not working.

Comment: Add a negative lookahead that makes sure the matched part is _not_ followed by another `[\S\_]`? (I did not try that, since the Cocoa regex API is too broken for a quick test.)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
let pat = "^#[^#\\s]{1,10}$"
let testStr = "#asd"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pat, options: [])
let matches = regex.matches(in: testStr, options: [], range: NSRange(testStr.startIndex..., in: testStr))

matches.count
```

Comment: Don't use `string.count` for creating the NSRange, that's wrong (and can cause a crash) if the string contains Emojis or other Unicode characters > U+FFFF. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880650/swift-extract-regex-matches.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but it seems that KILabel (the framework I'm using) is in Objective-C ... So I cannot use it in the file :/

Comment: @KevinB you can rewrite it in objc. this is very simple

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following regex:

```
initWithPattern:@"#\\S{1,25}(?!\\S)"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KP3TIx/1).

**Details**

- `#` - a `#` symbol
- `\S{1,25}` - 1 to 25 non-whitespace chars
- `(?!\S)` - no non-whitespace char is allowed immediately to the right of the current location.

The regex engine will match `#`, then will try to grab 25 non-whitespace chars (if there are fewer, it will backtrack to match fewer, but at least 1 non-whitespace char) and then will try to assert there is a whitespace or end of string after the non-whitespace chars.