# How to use regex to split string into groups of identical characters?

Tags: regex, swift, string

I got a string like this:

```
var string = "AAAAAAABBBCCCCCCDD"
```

and like to split the string into an array of this format (`same characters --> same group`) **using regular expressions**:

```
Array: "AAAAAAA", "BBB", "CCCCCC", "DD"
```

This Is what I got so far but tbh I can not really get it working.

---

```
var array = [String]()
var string = "AAAAAAABBBCCCCCCDD"
let pattern = "\\ b([1,][a-z])\\" // mistake?!
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])

array = regex.matchesInString(string, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.count))
```

Comment: Note that passing `string.count` to NSRange is wrong and can cause wrong results or crashes for strings containing "extended grapheme clusters".

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with a "back reference", compare
[NSRegularExpression](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsregularexpression):

> `\n`
>
> Back Reference. Match whatever the nth capturing group matched. n must be a number ≥ 1 and ≤ total number of capture groups in the pattern.

Example (using the utility method from [Swift extract regex matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880650/swift-extract-regex-matches/27880748#27880748)):

```
let string = "AAAAAAABBBCCCCCCDDE"
let pattern = "(.)\\1*"

let array = matches(for: pattern, in: string)
print(array)
// ["AAAAAAA", "BBB", "CCCCCC", "DD", "E"]
```

The pattern matches an arbitrary character, followed by zero or more
occurrences of *the same* character. If you are only interested in
repeating *word characters* use

```
let pattern = "(\\w)\\1*"
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using this function from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27880748/4763963):

```
func matches(for regex: String, in text: String) -> [String] {

    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex)
        let results = regex.matches(in: text,
                                    range: NSRange(text.startIndex..., in: text))
        return results.map {
            String(text[Range($0.range, in: text)!])
        }
    } catch let error {
        print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return []
    }
}
```

Passing `(.)\\1+` as `regex` and `AAAAAAABBBCCCCCCDD` as `text` like this:

```
let result = matches(for: "(.)\\1+", in: "AAAAAAABBBCCCCCCDD")
print(result) // ["AAAAAAA", "BBB", "CCCCCC", "DD"]
```