# Use regex to split groups starting and ending with specific character

Tags: arrays, regex, swift, string

I got a string like this ...

```
var string = "A12345678B119292A88B2222A883849B123"
```

---> (`var string =` `"`**A**`12345678`**B**`119292`**A**`88`**B**`2222`**A**`883849`**B**`123`")

... and like to split the string into specific groups starting with **'A'** and ending with '**B**' to get as result something like this:

```
resultArray: "12345678", "88", "883849"
```

---

This is what I found so far:

```
func matches(for regex: String, in text: String) -> [String] {

    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex)
        let results = regex.matches(in: text,
                                    range: NSRange(text.startIndex..., in: text))
        return results.map {
            String(text[Range($0.range, in: text)!])
        }
    } catch let error {
        print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return []
    }
}

let string = "A12345678B119292A88B2222A883849B123"
let pattern = "\\.*A.*B" // pattern error

let array = matches(for: pattern, in: string)
print(array)
```

`[?]` How is it possible to achieve this result using regex and Swift?

Comment: Also, please consider accepting/upvoting (green tick on the left) an answer [**to your other question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48137343/how-to-use-regex-to-split-string-into-groups-of-identical-characters) if it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with "positive lookbehind/lookahead"
(compare [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)):

```
let string = "A12345678B119292A88B2222A883849B123"
let pattern = "(?<=A).*?(?=B)"

let array = matches(for: pattern, in: string)
print(array)
// ["12345678", "88", "883849"]
```

The pattern matches an arbitrary sequence of characters,
preceded by an "A" and followed by a "B".

Note also the use 
of the "non-greedy" pattern `.*?`, otherwise you would get
a single match between the first "A" and the last "B".

Comment: The question is vaguely phrased, admittedly. I just inferred the need for digits from the `resultArray` but I might as well be wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have other examples, you may use

```
(?<=A)\d+(?=B)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/zxlDQW/3).

---

Note that you need to double escape backslashes, so that you need to write `(?<=A)\\d+(?=B)` instead.

Comment: `let pattern = "[AB]\d+"` will lead to the error `"Invalid escape sequence in literal"`

Comment: This would match any sequence of digits starting with A or B. OP wants only to match digits starting with A and ending with B. So the result would be  `["12345678", "119292", "88", "2222", "883849", "123"]` and thats not what OP asked

Comment: @LeoDabus: You are absolutely right, have updated the answer.