# How to filter text?

Tags: ios, swift

I have this text:

```
different text asdasd anasdasdd different text asdsdas @"1 my text" different text different text asdsdas @"2 my text" text different text asdsdas @"3 my text" @"4 my text" asdasd anasdasdd different
```

I want to filter this text. I want to delete all text except text in quotes. I want to get this result and show this in console:

```
@"1 my text"
@"2 my text"
@"3 my text"
@"4 my text"
```

How to do it?

Update:

sometimes my text look like this:

```
@"1 my \ntext"
@"1 my text"
@"1 \nmy \ntext"
@"\n1 my text"
```

with character `\n`

Comment: what have you tried so far?show some code

Comment: @maku I did not try anything. I do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this way,

```
let text = "different text asdasd anasdasdd different text asdsdas @\"1  my text\" different text different text asdsdas @\"2 my text\" text different text asdsdas @\"3 my text\" @\"4 my text\" asdasd anasdasdd different"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern:"@\"(.*?)\"", options: .dotMatchesLineSeparators)
var results = [String]()

regex.enumerateMatches(in: text, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, text.utf16.count)) { result, flags, stop in
    if let r = result?.range(at: 1), let range = Range(r, in: text) {
        results.append(String(text[range]))
    }
}

print(results)
```

Output will be like this,

```
["1  my text", "2 my text", "3 my text", "4 my text"]
```

FYI. You can create extension for the above function too for code optimization.

Comment: there are no any emojis in the given text

Comment: That even I don't know

Comment: @Moritz: `text.utf16.count` is exactly the right thing here. You can verify that this solution works correctly, even with emojis etc.

Comment: @MartinR Ok. Comment removed. I'll test that later in a Playground.

Comment: @Moritz There are no emojis in the my text

Comment: @PPL Yeah this is a good edit. I was wrong about the emojis and have deleted my comment. :)

Comment: @PPL its works. But sometimes I have this character in text `\n` and in this case code doesn't work. Text not displayed.

Comment: @PPL I updated question. I do not know exactly where in the text this `\n` will be. So I can not edit regex.

Comment: An alternative would be `NSRange(text.startIndex..., in: text)`, compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/27880748/1187415.