# How to remove new lines in a middle of a string using regex

Tags: ios, swift, string, trim

I am trying to figure out how to replace multiple breaks (`\n`) with a maximum breaks of two. I used [trimmingCharacters(in:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1415462-trimmingcharacters) to remove all the white spaces and new lines around the string, but I can't figure out how to remove the space within the string, or rather said: how could I replace more than 2 breaks to be maximum of 2 breaks?

#### For an instance:

If the user writes in a textView with spaces between the words, the string will be:

```
"Hello






I like coffee"
```

#### The string result I'd like to achieve:

```
"Hello

I like coffee"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do a regular expression replacement directly on a `String`:

```
extension String {
    func trimString() -> String {
        return replacingOccurrences(of: "\\n{3,}", with: "\n\n", options: .regularExpression)
    }
}
```

The `\n{3,}` pattern matches three or more newline characters.

Comment: The solution is perfect but if there is a space and then a new line will not remove it I better use this `(?:[\\t ]*(?:\\r?\\n|\\r))+`
this is your expression https://regex101.com/r/1PiFam/1 
, this is my  expression https://regex101.com/r/Cwosbp/1

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using a regular expression of: `\n{2,500}` and replaced all with `"\n\n"`.

**It's working perfectly!**

```
extension String {
    func trimString() -> String {
        let pattern = "\n{2,500}"
        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .dotMatchesLineSeparators)
        let range = NSMakeRange(0, self.count)
        let trimmedString = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: self, options: .reportProgress, range: range, withTemplate: "\n\n")
        return trimmedString
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `self.count` for computing the NSRange is not correct – try it with `"\n\n\nx"`. (Explanation here https://stackoverflow.com/a/27880748/1187415 :)

Comment: I tried to change it to something else and it didn't worked. I'm using the `self.count` to grab the length of the string. I checked out your link and I saw `NSMakeRange(0, nsString.length)`. Could you tell me what the difference is? By the way, I love your answer! @MartinR

Comment: NSRange is related to NSString and counts UTF-16 code units. `self.utf16.count` would also make it work.