# Finding substrings wrapped by special characters in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, regex, string, swift3

I have this String:

```
let string = "Users: [Ricky], [Bob], [Jane]"
```

and I'm trying to make a string **Array** (Ex. `["Ricky","Bob","Jane"]`) with words that are wrapped by brackets.

Question: **How do I substring and iterate results?**

Is Regex the way to go?

```
let string = "Users: [Ricky], [Bob], [Jane]"
let pattern = "/[(.*?)]/"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern)
let result = regex.matches(in:string, range:NSMakeRange(0, string.utf8.count))
```

Comment: Try `let pattern = "(?<=\\[).*?(?=\\])"`

Comment: Try `let pattern = "\[(.*?)\]"`. Also `NSRange` counts in UTF-16 code units so `NSMakeRange(0, string.utf16.count)`

Comment: Use my regex with code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880650/swift-extract-regex-matches).

Comment: It should be noted that the duplicate only has two (low vote) answers that are applicable to this question and none of them help the OP of this question determine what the proper regular expression needs to be.

Comment: @rmaddy, MartinR's answer provides everything needed except the pattern.  I reopened it because your pattern does work, as does all of your code.

Comment: @vacawama Martin's answer doesn't work in this case because it doesn't handle the capture group which is needed to avoid returning the `[ ]` from the results. His answer is great if you don't need capture groups.

Comment: @rmaddy, I used Wiktor's pattern with MartinR's code and it did the right thing.

Comment: @vacawama Indeed it does. It seems that RE gives just the part between the `[ ]`. Good to know. I'm not as familiar with the `?<=` and `?=` syntax. I need to study that.

Comment: @rmaddy, those are [lookahead and lookbehind assertions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Answer (score 2):

The following pattern is what you need:

```
let pattern = "\\[([^]]*)\\]"
```

`\\[` - a literal `[`

`[^]]*` - Any number of characters other than a `]`

`\\]` - a literal `]`

The `( )` are only needed if you need to reference the text inside the square brackets.

Here is complete working code:

```
let string = "Users: [Ricky], [Bob], [Jane]"
let pattern = "\\[([^]]*)\\]"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern)
let result = regex.matches(in:string, range:NSMakeRange(0, string.utf8.count))
let names = result.map { (string as NSString).substring(with: $0.range(at: 1)) }
print(names)
```

Output:

> ["Ricky", "Bob", "Jane"]