# Which Swift character count should I use with remove(first:)?

Tags: swift, string

There is a [`removeFirst(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2892932-removefirst) method on String. However, the documentation seems very generic and doesn't mention anything about being specific to a string:

> **k**: The number of elements to remove from the collection. k must be greater than or equal to zero and must not exceed the number of elements in the collection.
>
> ```
> var bugs = ["Aphid", "Bumblebee", "Cicada", "Damselfly", "Earwig"]
> bugs.removeFirst(3)
> print(bugs)
> // Prints "["Damselfly", "Earwig"]"
> ```

In fact, it looks very similar to the [Array](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2886730-removefirst) or [Collection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection/1640977-removefirst) documentation of removeFirst(_:).

Since there are at least [6 different ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51436417/which-swift-character-count-should-i-use-when-interacting-with-nsstring-apis) to get the character count in Swift, it makes it difficult to know which count I should use for `k`.

If I want to create a method such as `string.removePrefix("foo")`, which of the 6 character counts should I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`removeFirst(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rangereplaceablecollection/3018284-removefirst)
is a method of the `RangeReplaceableCollection` protocol, and for any collection, [`count`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection/3017670-count)
gives the number of its elements. So for any instance `a` of a `RangeReplaceableCollection` type,
the argument `k` passed to

```
a.removeFirst(k)
```

must be greater than or equal to zero, and less than or equal to `a.count`.

This applies to `Array`, `String` (which is a collection of `Character`)
and all other “range replaceable collection” types:

```
// Array:
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
arr.removeFirst(k)   // 0 <= k <= arr.count

// String:
var str = "‍‍‍"
str.removeFirst(k)   // 0 <= k <= str.count

// Unicode scalar view of a string:
var u = "‍‍‍".unicodeScalars
u.removeFirst(k)   // 0 <= k <= u.count
```

---

Having said that, I would implement the method as

```
extension String {
    func removingPrefix(_ prefix: String) -> String? {
        guard let range = range(of: prefix, options: .anchored) else {
            return nil
        }
        return String(self[range.upperBound...])
    }
}
```

to avoid unnecessary index/offset conversions.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Just wondering: how do you find out that removeFirst is part of RangeReplaceableCollection? When I jump to definition on String, it looks like it's implemented directly on String.

Comment: @Senseful: Actually it is a method of `RangeReplaceableCollection ` *and* a (restricted) method of  `Collection`. `String` may have its own implementation or use the default one, unfortunately that is not apparent (to me) from the documentation page. I *assumed* that it is a protocol extension method, and then grep'ed in the source code.

Answer (score 0):

It appears it expects you to use `string.count`.

Playground test:

```
func test(_ string: String, _ desc: String? = nil) {
  var s = string
  s.removeFirst(1)
  print("\(string) -> \(s)")
  assert(string.count == s.count + 1)
}

test("abc")
test("❌")
test("")
test("☾test")
test("‍‍‍")
test("\u{200d}\u{200d}\u{200d}")
test("")
test("\u{1F468}")
test("‍♀️‍♂️")
test("你好吗")
test("مرحبا", "Arabic word")
test("م", "Arabic letter")
test("שלום", "Hebrew word")
test("ם", "Hebrew letter")
```

Output:

```
abc -> bc
❌ -> 
 -> 
☾test -> test
‍‍‍ -> 
‍‍‍ -> 
 -> 
 -> 
‍♀️‍♂️ -> ‍♀️‍♂️
你好吗 -> 好吗
مرحبا -> رحبا
م -> 
שלום -> לום
ם ->
```

<strike>So you could create:</strike>

```
extension String {

  /// Removes a prefix from a string, if it exists.
  ///
  /// - Parameter prefix: The prefix to attempt to remove.
  /// - Returns: The string without the prefix, or `nil` if the prefix didn't exist.
  func removingPrefix(_ prefix: String) -> String? {
    guard starts(with: prefix) else {
      return nil
    }

    var result = self
    result.removeFirst(prefix.count)
    return result
  }
}
```

See [Martin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51992590/35690) for a better implementation