# Swift - Regex to extract value

Tags: ios, swift, regex

I want to extract value from a string which has unique starting and ending character. In my case its *em*

```
"Fully <em>Furni<\/em>shed |Downtown and Canal Views",
```

result

> Furnished

Comment: Is that `<em>` tag the only HTML content in your string?  In general you should not be parsing HTML using regex.

Comment: Yeah thats the only tag. Thats my perception to use regex to extract it since its a pattern. Is there a better way

Comment: What's the logic? I would have expected result: `Furni` (the only text embraced by the `em` tag). But you seem to expect `Furnished`. So what if it's `Fur<em>ni</em>shed`. Do you expect `nished`? `Furnished`? `Furni`? `ni`?

Comment: Try `let res = s.replacingOccurrences(of: ".*<em>(\\S*?)</em>(\\S*).*", with: "$1$2", options: .regularExpression)`

Comment: @Larme it would always be in this format
<em>Furni<\/em>shed
<em>balc<\/em>ony
<em>gard<\/em>en

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you want to remove the tags.

If the backslash is only virtual the pattern is pretty simple: Basically `<em>` with optional slash `/?`

```
let trimmedString = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "</?em>", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
```

Considering also the backslash it's

```
let trimmedString = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "<\\\\?/?em>", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
```

---

If you want to extract only *`Furnished`* you have to capture groups: The string between the tags and everything after the closing tag until the next whitespace character.

```
let string = "Fully <em>Furni<\\/em>shed |Downtown and Canal Views"
let pattern = "<em>(.*)<\\\\?/em>(\\S+)"
do {
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern)
    if let match = regex.firstMatch(in: string, range: NSRange(string.startIndex..., in: string)) {
        let part1 = string[Range(match.range(at: 1), in: string)!]
        let part2 = string[Range(match.range(at: 2), in: string)!]
        print(String(part1 + part2))
    }
} catch { print(error) }
```

Comment: I dont want to remove the tags only - I want to extra word between `em`

Comment: This won't catch valid html variations like `<em >` (space before the closing angular bracket).

Answer (score 4):

Given this string:

```
let str = "Fully <em>Furni<\\/em>shed |Downtown and Canal Views"
```

and the corresponding `NSRange`:

```
let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: (str as NSString).length)
```

Let's construct a regular expression that would match letters between `<em>` and `</em>`, or preceded by `</em>`

```
let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(?<=<em>)\\w+(?=<\\\\/em>)|(?<=<\\\\/em>)\\w+")
```

What it does is :

- look for 1 or more letters: `\\w+`,
- that are preceded by `<em>`: `(?<=<em>)` (positive *lookbehind*),
- and followed by `<\/em>`: `(?=<\\\\/em>)` (positive *lookahead*),
- or : `|`
- letters: `\\w+`,
- that are preceded by `<\/em>`: `(?=<\\\\/em>)` (positive *lookbehind*)

Let's get the matches:

```
let matches = regex.matches(in: str, range: range)
```

Which we can turn into substrings:

```
let strings: [String] = matches.map { match in
    let start = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: match.range.location)
    let end = str.index(start, offsetBy: match.range.length)
    return String(str[start..<end])
}
```

Now we can join the strings in even indices, with the ones in odd indices:

```
let evenStride = stride(from: strings.startIndex,
               to: strings.index(strings.endIndex, offsetBy: -1),
               by: 2)
let result = evenStride.map { strings[$0] + strings[strings.index($0, offsetBy: 1)]}

print(result)  //["Furnished"]
```

---

We can test it with another string:

```
let str2 = "<em>Furni<\\/em>shed <em>balc<\\/em>ony <em>gard<\\/em>en"
```

the result would be:

```
["Furnished", "balcony", "garden"]
```

Comment: This won't catch valid html variations like `<em >` (space before the closing angular bracket).

Comment: @Cristik That’s an easy fix, the main idea would still be the same. The OP hasn’t mentioned such a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Not a regex but, for obtaining all words in tags, e.g [Furni, sma]:

```
let text = "Fully <em>Furni<\\/em>shed <em>sma<\\/em>shed |Downtown and Canal Views"
let emphasizedParts = text.components(separatedBy: "<em>").filter { $0.contains("<\\/em>")}.flatMap { $0.components(separatedBy: "<\\/em>").first }
```

For full words, e.g [Furnished, smashed]:

```
let emphasizedParts = text.components(separatedBy: " ").filter { $0.contains("<em>")}.map { $0.replacingOccurrences(of: "<\\/em>", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: "<em>", with: "") }
```

Comment: This won't catch valid html variations like `<em >` (space before the closing angular bracket).

Comment: Not a requirement + you can always do preprocessing.

Answer (score 1):

**Regex:**

If you want to achieve that by regex, you can use [Valexa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47671579/1290278):

```
public extension String {
    public func capturedGroups(withRegex pattern: String) -> [String] {
        var results = [String]()

        var regex: NSRegularExpression
        do {
            regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])
        } catch {
            return results
        }
        let matches = regex.matches(in: self, options: [], range: NSRange(location:0, length: self.count))

        guard let match = matches.first else { return results }

        let lastRangeIndex = match.numberOfRanges - 1
        guard lastRangeIndex >= 1 else { return results }

        for i in 1...lastRangeIndex {
            let capturedGroupIndex = match.range(at: i)
            let matchedString = (self as NSString).substring(with: capturedGroupIndex)
            results.append(matchedString)
        }

        return results
    }
}
```

like this:

```
let text = "Fully <em>Furni</em>shed |Downtown and Canal Views"
print(text.capturedGroups(withRegex: "<em>([a-zA-z]+)</em>"))
```

result:

> ["Furni"]

**NSAttributedString:**

If you want to do some highlighting or you only need to get rid of tags or any other reason that you can't use the first solution, you can also do that using `NSAttributedString`:

```
extension String {
    var attributedStringAsHTML: NSAttributedString? {
        do{
            return try NSAttributedString(data: Data(utf8),
                                          options: [
                                            .documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                                            .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
                                          documentAttributes: nil)
        }
        catch {
            print("error: ", error)
            return nil
        }
    }

}

func getTextSections(_ text:String) -> [String] {
    guard let attributedText = text.attributedStringAsHTML else {
        return []
    }
    var sections:[String] = []
    let range = NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.length)

    // we don't need to enumerate any special attribute here,
    // but for example, if you want to just extract links you can use `NSAttributedString.Key.link` instead
    let attribute: NSAttributedString.Key = .init(rawValue: "")

    attributedText.enumerateAttribute(attribute,
                                      in: range,
                                      options: .longestEffectiveRangeNotRequired) {attribute, range, pointer in

                                        let text = attributedText.attributedSubstring(from: range).string
                                        sections.append(text)
    }
    return sections
}

let text = "Fully <em>Furni</em>shed |Downtown and Canal Views"
print(getTextSections(text))
```

result:

> ["Fully ", "Furni", "shed |Downtown and Canal Views"]

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to extract the text between `<em>` and `<\/em>` (note this is not normal HTML tags as then it would have been `<em>` and `</em>`) tags, we can simply capture this pattern and replace it with the group 1's value captured. And we don't need to worry about what is present around the matching text and just replace it with whatever got captured between those text which could actually be empty string, because OP hasn't mentioned any constraint for that. The regex for matching this pattern would be this,

```
<em>(.*?)<\\\/em>
```

OR to be technically more robust in taking care of optional spaces (as I saw someone pointing out in comment's of other answers) present any where within the tags, we can use this regex,

```
<\s*em\s*>(.*?)<\s*\\\/em\s*>
```

And replace it with `\1` or `$1` depending upon where you are doing it. Now whether these tags contain empty string, or contains some actual string within it, doesn't really matter as shown in my demo on regex101.

[Here is the demo](https://regex101.com/r/FAwwOH/1)

Let me know if this meets your requirements and further, if any of your requirement remains unsatisfied.

Comment: As we do not always have the backslash, I guess this should work better: `(<\s*em\s*>(.*?)<\s*\\?\/em\s*>)`

Answer (score -1):

Here is basic implementation in PHP (yes, I know you asked Swift, but it's to demonstrate the regex part):

```
<?php

$in = "Fully <em>Furni</em>shed |Downtown and Canal Views";

$m = preg_match("/<([^>]+)>([^>]+)<\/\\1>([^ ]+|$)/i", $in, $t);    

$s = $t[2] . $t[3];

echo $s;
```

Output:

```
ZC-MGMT-04:~ jv$ php -q regex.php
Furnished
```

Obviously, the most important bit is the regular expression part which would match any tag and find a respective closing tag and reminder afterward

Answer (score -1):

I highly recommend the use of [regex capture groups](https://www.advancedswift.com/regex-capture-groups/).

1. create your regex putting the name for the desired capture group:

```swift
let capturePattern = "(?<=<em>)(?<data1>\\w+)(?=<\\\\/em>)|(?<=<\\\\/em>)(?<data2>\\w+)"
```

2. now use the Swift capture pattern to get the data:

```swift
let captureRegex = try! NSRegularExpression(
    pattern: capturePattern,
    options: []
)

let textInput = "Fully <em>Furni<\/em>shed |Downtown and Canal Views"
let textInputRange = NSRange(
    textInput.startIndex..<textInput.endIndex,
    in: textInput
)

let matches = captureRegex.matches(
    in: textInput,
    options: [],
    range: textInputRange
)

guard let match = matches.first else {
    // Handle exception
    throw NSError(domain: "", code: 0, userInfo: nil)
}

let data1Range = match.range(withName: "data1")

// Extract the substring matching the named capture group
if let substringRange = Range(data1Range, in: textInput) {
   let capture = String(textInput[substringRange])
   print(capture)
}
```

The same can be done to get the `data2` group name:

```swift
let data2Range = match.range(withName: "data2")

if let substringRange = Range(data2Range, in: textInput) {
   let capture = String(textInput[substringRange])
   print(capture)
}
```

This method's main advantage is the group index independency. This makes this use less attached to the regex expression.